# syncing iostream with stdio

Tags: c++, c, stl, io, legacy-code

I am trying to add iostream to the legacy code and thus  want to sync those two libraries.
According to this [article](http://www.ddj.com/article/printableArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=1TRM2O2DD5CJ5QE1GHPSKHWATMY32JVN?articleID=184401305&dept_url=/cpp/),  I should use std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio.

Now, I wonder how it is used in practice (examples please), side-effects I should be aware of.

Thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default the streams are synchronized, it's guaranteed to work by the standard, you don't have to do anything. `sync_with_stdio` is only here to disable synchronisation if you want to.

From the article you mentioned :

> For the predefined streams, it's safe
>   to mix stdio and iostreams. For
>   example, you can safely use stdin and
>   cin in the same program; the C++
>   Standard guarantees that it will work
>   the way you would naively expect it
>   to.

The only drawback is a potential performance hit (I guess that's why it can be disabled).

Comment: I remember doing some benchmark, and by default `cout` was slower than `printf`, until I disabled `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio`, when `cout` became faster. Unfortunately I don't have the numbers...

Comment: performance hit can be 10x, according to banchmarks here: 
[Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

As TheSamFrom1984 says, synced is the default so it should not be a problem.  However synchronisation is only relevant when the same stream is being operated on by both libraries.  This typically occurs when using cin/cout/cerr and stdin/stdout/stderr respectively.  However I can see few reasons for needing to use both simultaneously except when reusing legacy code.

When I first started using C++ I found myself doing this because often I knew how to do something using stdio, but did not know how to do it with iostream, but a better approach would be to figure out how to do in in one or the other, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio()`:

> ```
> static bool sync_with_stdio( bool sync = true );
> ```

It sets whether the standard C++ streams are synchronized to the standard C streams after each input/output operation.

The standard C++ streams are the following: `std::cin`, `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::clog`, `std::wcin`, `std::wcout`, `std::wcerr` and `std::wclog`.

The standard C streams are the following: `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

In practice, this means that the synchronized C++ streams are unbuffered, and each I/O operation on a C++ stream is immediately applied to the corresponding C stream's buffer. This makes it possible to freely mix C++ and C I/O.

Also, synchronized C++ streams are guaranteed to be thread-safe (individual characters output from multiple threads may interleave, but no data races occur)

If the synchronization is turned off, the C++ standard streams are allowed to buffer their I/O independently, which may be considerably faster in some cases.

By default, all eight standard C++ streams are synchronized with their respective C streams.

If this function is called after I/O has occurred on the standard stream, the behavior is implementation-defined: implementations range from no effect to destroying the read buffer.

---

Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cout << "a\n";
    std::printf("b\n");
    std::cout << "c\n";
}
```

Output:

```
b
a
c
```

---

Source: *[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio)*