# Speed and stability of libraries 'stdio' vs. 'iostream'

Tags: c++, io, iostream, stdio

When I search on the Internet for the difference between these two libraries, everyone says that `<iostream>` is the standard I/O library of C++ and `<cstdio>` is for C.

My professor says that `cin>>` and `cout<<` are not good functions and if we use `cin>>` many times, our application will definitely crash. He also says that `stdio` provides nearly three times faster input and output than `iostream`. However, I prefer using `iostream` because it is more convenient, and also I don't know if my professor is right.

What do you advise me to use?

Comment: Use whichever is more appropriate for your application. Also, "if we use cin>> many times our application will definitely crash" is... superstitious.

Comment: *"if we use cin>> many times our application will definitely crash"*. I haven't experienced it yet, not once.

Comment: You need to find a different teacher, or if that is not possible realize that your current teacher is ignorant and learn to ignore.

Comment: @paxdiablo I agree with you :D

Comment: @paxdiablo Or still haven't visited [so]. ;-)

Answer (score 17):

Using `iostream` should not make your program crash. It can be slow, but that's only because it's trying to interoperate with `stdio`. That synchronization can be turned off<sup>1</sup>. `iostream` is the idiomatic C++ way to get input, and I'd recommend its use over `stdio` functions in most cases when using C++.

<sup>1</sup> using `std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);`

Comment: @Sam379 You can also read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python?rq=1

Comment: There are situations where stdio is preferable; this kind of blanket statement isn't necessarily helpful...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, And even better, we can have type safe versions, decreasing some of the danger of using the C ones.

Comment: @Oli: I imagine there are indeed such situations, but I can't immediately think of one; would you mind giving an example or two of situations where `stdio` might be preferable?

Comment: @icktoofay: Well, performing formatted I/O is usually (but not always) more succinct and clearer when using `printf` than messing around with stream manipulators.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth `Boost.Format`. Also, clearer in what terms? The fact that specification of `sprintf` makes it essentially impossible to write reasonable code with it (unknown output length) isn't really welcoming (i.e. You can use it and the syntax is shorter, but it will crash). Now *that's* messing around.

Answer (score 9):

Use streams in C++ and stdio.h in C. 
Yes, streams are a bit slower, but do those milliseconds count? User input is rarely a bottleneck of an application.

And if streams are used properly, and your compiler/runtime libraries are ok, your application *won't* crash.

But, if you have good, explainable reasons to use `cstdio` functions, then it is fully legitimate to use them in C++ as well.

Comment: It's not just user input, it's any interaction with files...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: you are completely right, I've written "input" because the question goes primarily about `cin`.

Comment: This is misleading. Any program that produces an even moderately sized output will see a great difference between using cout and printf

Comment: @andrepd, this depends on the definitions of "moderately sized" (output) and "great" (difference). For tools like `tail`, it surely matters, for business applications it _usually_ doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

Unless performance of the I/O *really* matters, use whichever makes your program the clearest (easiest to read).

In the vast number of programs I've written, only a few have needed special treatment to "how fast the I/O is" - and most of the problem with `std::stream` functions has to to with the actual parsing of the input (as well as sync with *stdio*) - which, if you are reading, say, floating point numbers, will be quite difficult to write your own version of (that accepts the full range of formats that `std::stream` allows).

If I/O performance *really* matters, then using `std::stream::read` and `std::stream::write` may be the solution, but in most cases, best performance comes from using the non-portable `mmap` and `MapViewOfFile` interfaces that "map" the contents of a file directly from the filesystem to the virtual memory of the application. This saves on the amount of copying the processing of the data takes, and will make it a little faster.

Answer (score 1):

The iostreams library probably is slower than the lower-level stdio library. Streams does a lot more under the covers - type conversions, localization, exception handling, etc.