# Fast Input function for reading std::string in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

Is there any method for fast input of `std::string` in `c++`, instead of using `std::cin`?

As for fast input of numbers we can use `getchar_unlocked()` in our custom function.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why isn't `std::cin` fast enough? (Well, yeah, I/O is slow. And using a different function won't change it.)

Comment: Define what you mean by "fast input of `std::string`" ...

Comment: Just for curiosity and adding to my knowledge a method of inputting strings faster than naive std::cin.

Comment: @H2CO3: probably because `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` and `std::cin.tie(0)` were not called.

Comment: By Fast Input I mean a method to improve overall running time of our code where a part of problem solving is inputting a large number of strings

Comment: Inputting a large number of strings from where?  A human typing them in?  A pipe?  A file?

Comment: If it is coming from standard input, it won't matter how fast you make the input ... the bottleneck is the user (which you can't change).

Comment: Do you mean unbuffered?

Comment: @H2CO3: Because of tons of virtual locale facet lookups perhaps?

Comment: @KerrekSB So is the cost of a virtual function call comparable to that of I/O itself?

Comment: Relevant: [Fast textfile reading in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17925143/85371)

Comment: @H2CO3: Not as such, but I think there may be encoding conversions that have the potential of being costly. Not sure if the default locale has some kind of optimized no-op conversion...