# Why does Java read a big file faster than C++?

Tags: java, c++, file

I have a 2 GB file (`iputfile.txt`) in which every line in the file is a word, just like:

```
apple
red
beautiful
smell
spark
input
```

I need to write a program to read every word in the file and print the word count. I wrote it using Java and C++, but the result is surprising: Java runs 2.3 times faster than C++. My code are as follows:

C++:

```
int main() {
    struct timespec ts, te;
    double cost;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);

    ifstream fin("inputfile.txt");
    string word;
    int count = 0;
    while(fin >> word) {
        count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &te);
    cost = te.tv_sec - ts.tv_sec + (double)(te.tv_nsec-ts.tv_nsec)/NANO;
    printf("Run time: %-15.10f s\n", cost);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5e+08
Run time: 69.311 s
```

Java:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    FileReader reader = new FileReader("inputfile.txt");
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
    String str = null;
    int count = 0;
    while((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);

    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Run time : " + (endTime - startTime)/1000 + "s");
}
```

Output:

```
5.0E8
Run time: 29 s
```

Why is Java faster than C++ in this situation, and how do I improve the performance of C++?

Comment: Run the C++ version, then the Java version, then the C++ version again. This may catch system caching. (However, 69 seconds is quite long even accounting for disk I/O).

Comment: Also, have you compiled with or without optimizations (-O) turned on?

Comment: Did you try with plain C? Try compare with typical C and adjust block and buffer sizes, that would be interesting.

Comment: @nneonneo I didn't use any -O optimization. If I need it, what level should I use ? Now I wonder that whether the C++ stream(fin) is slow than Java BufferReader?

Comment: @user3513917 C++ STL implementations usually perform poorly when used without compiler optimizations like inlining. You should never even look at the performance of a C++ program with optimizations turned off; it's meaningless.

Comment: You run `readline` in Java code and `ifstream>>` in C++ code. When you run `>>` you read data on character basis, in other words your disk head moves like this (Read 1 character)=>(Input in `word`)=>repeat. In other words to read the word "apple" your disk head moves 5 times carrying 1 character, while in Java code your disk head moves 1 time carrying 5 character block (virtually speaking). The trick here is that the most time spent in I/O operations is exactly on disk head movements. This might not be exactly precise, but generally speaking it's true.

Comment: @ConstantineSamoilenko Yes, this is a bottleneck in my C++ code, I change it by using getline(fin, word), and use -O2 optimation. Now C++ run 38s and Java run 32s. Java is still faster than C++. i don't know whether C++ can be faster than Java.

Comment: @ConstantineSamoilenko There's no movement of the disk heads involved here; the data is buffered.  (The tests needed to detect the end of a word _may_ be more complex than those needed to detect the end of a line, but otherwise, `>>` and `getline` are pretty similar.  Both need to look at each character read.)

Comment: You way of reading the file is unrealistic. Read the file in large chunks and time that. And you shouldn't time the console prints anyway.

Comment: why do you use double for counting? 5e8 is fine within int's range. It'll take less memory and run faster

Comment: @self. His way of reading the file is perfectly realistic; both the C++ `std::filebuf` and Java's `BufferedReader` should use buffering optimized for the given platform.  If you can improve on it, then there's something wrong with the implementation.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Yes, this is a mistake, I should have use the int.

Comment: One detail: C++ doesn't automatically initialize your variable **count** to zero.

Comment: I am not too surprised that Java is a bit faster than C++ iostreams. The iostreams design suffers from being object oriented and using virtual functions. Unlike a Java virtual machine, C++ cannot translate virtual calls into inline calls. You get better performance by using the C stdio functions which just read data rather than trying to support virtual data sources and virtual format operations.

Comment: Oh yeah. It is *theoretically* possible for the C++ compiler to inline virtual calls if you promise it that the binary is self contained. If using GCC try the `-fwhole-program` option when compiling.

Comment: What platform is this for? Using the native file I/O API's will probably give a big performance boost

Comment: Even using `fopen` and `fscanf` will give a big performance boost.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast textfile reading in c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925051/fast-textfile-reading-in-c)

Comment: OT: Why write a programm at all? `wc` is the tool to go wc -w $filename done.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You aren't comparing the same thing. The Java program reads lines, depening on the newline, while the C++ program reads white space delimited "words", which is a little extra work.

Try `istream::getline`.

**Later**

You might also try and do an elementary read operation to read a byte array and scan this for newlines.

**Even later**

On my old Linux notebook, jdk1.7.0_21 and don't-tell-me-it's-old 4.3.3 take about the same time, comparing with C++ getline. (We have established that reading words is slower.) There isn't much difference between -O0 and -O2, which doesn't surprise me, given the simplicity of the code in the loop.

**Last note**
As I suggested, fin.read(buffer,LEN) with LEN = 1MB and using memchr to scan for '\n' results in another speed improvement of about 20%, which makes C (there isn't any C++ left by now) faster than Java.

Comment: Why use double for counting?

Comment: I use getline(fin, word), the result is 43s , Java is still faster than it.

Comment: @dodolong: DONT Compare the debug builds. Use optimizations.

Comment: On Linux, the preprocessing of a text file is a no-op, and I expect that most implementations will recognize this, and simply ignore the text/binary options.  On all other systems, the preprocessing necessary to convert what is read to the text format will impact performance in C++.

Comment: @dodolong: Who says that C++ has to be faster than Java? JIT will kick in fast enough, and there's C at the bottom of Java as well.

Comment: @laune No one has said anything about pure CPU performance (which can vary---in the end, both Java and C++ will be compiled to machine code, more or less optimally).  The issue here is IO.

Comment: Concerning your last note: it also makes the processing significantly more complicated.  What is the effect if you set the buffer size on the `std::filebuf` to 1MB?

Comment: @James Kanze Using a 1MB buffer with ifstream and getline reduces the time by 10%. The other 10% the "pure C" version gains should be due to avoiding the getline calls.

Comment: +1 for eventually devolving into C for the sake of performance.

Comment: I'm sure using ZwCreateFile and ZwReadFile on windows in C++ would beat Java and C due to cutting out many buffer copies

Comment: @JamesKanze: With C++ iostreams, the performance limiter is rarely the I/O system.  The facets logic is very slow.  At least on common implementations.

Comment: @BenVoigt The required use of the `codecvt` facet in `std::filebuf` can slow things down considerably if not implemented correctly; it doesn't have to, but as you point out, in many common implementations, it does.  Still, if the data isn't already cached by the system, it can take around 10ms to get the 8K buffer from the disk.  Even a poor implementation of `std::filebuf` will not need anywhere near 10ms to remap the buffer.

Comment: @James: 10ms seek time, sure.  But OSes use read-ahead caching, so you aren't paying 10ms per 8KB block.  More like 10ms seek time + 10ms transfer time per 1MB block (assuming minimal fragmentation).  And unfortunately, `std::filebuf` often does take more than 20ms/MB on popular implementations.

Comment: If you set a 1MB buffer for the C version you should do the same for the Java version (constructor parameter for `BufferedReader`).

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of significant differences in the way the
languages handle [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output), all of which can make a difference, one way
or another.

Perhaps the first (and most important) question is: how is the
data encoded in the text file. If it is single-byte characters
([ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)), then Java has to convert it into [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2)
before processing; depending on the locale, C++ may (or may not)
also convert or do some additional checking.

As has been pointed out (partially, at least), in C++, `>>` uses
a locale specific `isspace`, `getline` will simply compare for
`'\n'`, which is probably faster. (Typical implementations of
`isspace` will use a bitmap, which means an additional memory
access for each character.)

Optimization levels and specific library implementations may
also vary. It's not unusual in C++ for one library
implementation to be 2 or 3 times faster than another.

Finally, a most significant difference: C++ distinguishes
between text files and binary files. You've opened the file in
text mode; this means that it will be "preprocessed" at the
lowest level, before even the extraction operators see it. This
depends on the platform: for Unix platforms, the "preprocessing"
is a no-op; on Windows, it will convert CRLF pairs into `'\n'`,
which will have a definite impact on performance. If I recall
correctly (I've not used Java for some years), Java expects
higher level functions to handle this, so functions like
`readLine` will be slightly more complicated. Just guessing
here, but I suspect that the additional logic at the higher
level costs less in runtime than the buffer preprocessing at the
lower level. (If you are testing under Windows, you might
experiment with opening the file in binary mode in C++. This
should make no difference in the behavior of the program when
you use `>>`; any extra CR will be considered white space. With
`getline`, you'll have to add logic to remove any trailing
`'\r'` to your code.)

Answer (score 5):

I would suspect that the main difference is that `java.io.BufferedReader` performs better than the `std::ifstream` because it buffers, while the ifsteam does not. The BufferedReader reads large chunks of the file in advance and hands them to your program from RAM when you call `readLine()`, while the std::ifstream only reads a few bytes at a time when you prompt it to by calling the `>>`-operator.

Sequential access of large amounts of data from the hard drive is usually much faster than accessing many small chunks one at a time.

A fairer comparison would be to compare std::ifstream to the unbuffered java.io.FileReader.

Comment: `std::ifstream` forwards to `std::filebuf`, which normally buffers.  (The standard only requires a one character buffer, but most implementations will use something like 8K.)

Answer (score 4):

I am not expert in C++, but you have at least the following to affect performance:

1. OS level caching for the file
2. For Java you are using a buffered reader and the buffer size defaults to a page or something. I am not sure how C++ streams does this.
3. Since the file is so big that JIT would probably be kicked in, and it probably compiles the Java byte code better than if you don't turn any optimization on for your C++ compiler.

Since [I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input/output) cost is the major cost here, I guess 1 and 2 are the major reasons.

Comment: Given his description, I'm sure that the differing buffering strategies plays a significant roll.

Comment: Yeah, given that the program is probably I/O-bound and the JIT compiler will take care of the central loop anyway, one wouldn't expect any inherent advantage for C++.

Answer (score 2):

I would also try using [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) instead of standard file read/write. This should let your OS handle the reading and writing while your application is only concerned with the data.

There's no situation where C++ can't be faster than Java, but sometimes it takes a lot of work from very talented people. But I don't think this one should be too hard to beat as it is a straightforward task.

mmap for Windows is described in *[File Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* ([MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)).

Comment: If we want to compare mmap implementations we should use FileChannel in Java as well.