# read large chunk into memory and process line by line

Tags: performance, file, c++11

I want to read and process a large text file efficiently, accoding to many posts on SO, it's advised to read large chunk of file into memory and do processing in memory.

I try to do it this way:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(path, "r");
char chunk[SIZE];
while (fread(chunk, SIZE, 1, fp)) {
  process_chunk_line_by_line(chunk);
}
```

The problem is, what if the last line in `chunk`is incomplete, I should not process that last line, should seek `fp` back by the length of the incomplete last line? Is there any more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Slightly more efficient would be to copy the incomplete line back to beginning of the buffer, and then read into the space after the partial line directly. `seek`ing would likely lead to additional system calls that keeping the file pointer in place would avoid. Side-note: `stdio` already buffers, so odds are, you're already doing chunked reads. Increasing the size of the `stdio` buffers might get you most of the benefit without needing to chunk yourself.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, but I have to check incompleteless of last line any way, do I?

Comment: @ShadowRanger, Andrew's answer clears my doubts, and now I understand what you mean by "increasing the size of stdio buffers", thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the easiest way I know to do what you want by using already-existing `stdio` library functions.  (`stdio` since that's what you're already using and what you seem to be familiar with.  There are other ways to do this with C++ streams.)

`stdio` files opened using `fopen()` already buffer input, and your OS likely uses a page cache.  Adding another layer of buffering in your application means there would be *three* layers of buffering between the data on disk and your application processing the data:  1) the page cache 2) the `stdio` buffer, 3) your `chunk`.  As @ShadowRanger commented - just use the `stdio` buffer, then you can use the [standard `getline()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html) to read lines.

```
// change size to suit your requirements
#define BUFSIZE ( 16UL * 1024UL * 1024UL )
FILE *fp = fopen( path, "rb" );

// assuming a POSIX OS - could also use malloc()/free()
char *buffer = ( char * ) mmap( NULL, BUFSIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0 );
setvbuf( fp, buffer, _IOFBF, BUFSIZE );

char *line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;

for ( ;; )
{
    ssize_t currentLen = getline( &line, &len, fp );
    if ( currentLen < 0 )
    {
        break;
    }

    // process line
}

free( line );
fclose( fp );
munmap( buffer, BUFSIZE );
```

You'll need to add error checking along with the proper header files.

That should do exactly what you want, and *you* don't have to write code that has to figure out where lines end, nor do you have to deal with lines that span across multiple `fread()` calls.

And it might be even faster if you bypass the page cache.  The above code already uses a 16 MB cache.  Additional caching just adds another copy in the data path from disk to application.  Since you don't need to seek, and you're not going to re-read data, the page cache in this usage pattern does you no good.  On Linux, of your file system supports direct IO, you can do this:

```
int fd = open( path, O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT );
FILE *fp = fdopen( fd, "rb" );
```

Note that direct IO has significant restrictions - your IO buffer may have to be page-aligned.  One nice thing about `mmap()` is that it returns page-aligned memory...

If the filesystem supports direct IO, that will bypass the page cache, and your read operations could be substantially faster and might put a lot less memory pressure on your machine, especially if the file is extremely large.

Comment: According to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17925051/2235936, `getline` doesn't look like a good way to go though.

Comment: OH, I just found out what you meant by `setvbuf` and `mmap` (which I omitted at first glance), you actually read a large chunk from file and buffer it into an array mapped with `mmap`, and then `getline` would be operate on that in-memory buffer, right? that's clever :-)

Comment: And, I could remove the `mmap` part if I don't care about *page-aligned memory*, right? I just don't quite get the advantage of `mmap` here.

Comment: @loganecolss - The default `stdio` buffer size is only a few kilobytes.  So you need to get a larger memory buffer from somewhere - whether it's from `mmap()` or `malloc()` or `new` or `posix_memalign()`. If you're running on Linux, larger allocations fall back to `mmap()` anyway. The page-aligned memory is usually necessary for direct IO, which bypasses the page cache. Just reading a large file like this - stream it from start to end, without re-reading or changing any part of it - is a perfect use of direct IO since the page cache provides no benefits when you never re-read or update data.

Comment: @loganecolss "According to this one: stackoverflow.com/q/17925051/2235936, `getline` doesn't look like a good way to go though."  That's the C++ `getline` that operates on a C++ `ifstream`.  Note also that the fastest implementation on that question uses low-level `open()`/`read()` operations - and that could possibly go even faster by using direct IO, and a larger page-aligned buffer.  But direct IO isn't supported by all file systems, and on Linux it can be very particular - such as allowing *only* page-sized IO requests, which makes reading/writing the last few bytes of a file impossible.

Comment: I see, so `mmap` would be beneficial overall.