# How is memory managed when creating a map<string,vector<string> > by reading files

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, stdmap

I am wondering how is memory managed when different files are stored in a map of string vectors.
I have tried to read different files of 10 mo each to put them in memory and when I check the memory with KSySGuard, the memory appearing is more than twice the memory of my files (~70mo).
I give you a code example for it:
There is a function readfile():

```
std::vector<std::string> read_file(std::string& path){
    ifstream fichier(path);
    std::vector<std::string> fich;
    if(fichier){
       string ligne;
        while(getline(fichier, ligne)){
           fich.push_back(ligne);
        }
     }
    fichier.close();
    return fich;
}
```

This function is used in another which is building my map:

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> buildmap(std::string folder){
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::string>> evaluations; std::vector<std::string> vecFiles = {"file1","file2","file3"};
    for( auto i = 0; i < vecFiles.size(); i++ )
    {
        std::stringstream strad;
        strad <<vecFiles[i] ;
        std::string path(folder+vecFiles[i]);
        std::vector<std::string> a = read_file(path);
        evaluations[strad.str()]=a;
    }
    return evaluations;   
}
```

So, I do not understand why the memory is so high compared to the files sizes. Is-there a more efficient way to construct this kind of container?

Comment: Totally unrelated to your question, but why the string stream `strad`? Why not use `vecFile[i]` directly? You don't even need the `path` variable (if you make `read_file` take a **`const`** reference instead, which you really should).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is vector array doubled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424826/why-is-vector-array-doubled)

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> a = read_file(path);
        evaluations[strad.str()]=a;` That's a copy, you could move it (actuallyu use an move insertion instead).

Comment: A stack of papers doesn't take up much space in a drawer, but it's awfully slow to find the one you want. A stack of papers organized for efficient location is going to take up a lot more space.

Comment: A `std::string` will have some overhead. A lot of lines in your files would mean a lot of `std::string`s and more overhead. You should be able to reduce the overhead some by using `std::vector<char>` instead but I'm not so sure it's something you want to do.

Comment: some programmer dude. Right, it s a mistake of my paste here, I modify.
tom, i will read it.
Matthieu, yes, I can change this, but it does not reduce the memory.
David, even by storing it in a vector of vector does not reduce the memory.
super, i will think of it, I do not really know what it implies

Comment: @Tom I wouldn't say _duplicate_. The question you linked is _relavant_, but I dare to guess that a non-negligible amount of memory overhead is caused by a lot of separate `std::string` objects as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of memory overhead in your scenario:

1. You store each file line as a separate `std::string` object. Each such object occupies some space (typically 24 or 32 bytes on a 64-bit architecture) itself, however, the stored string (line characters) are stored inside it only when the string is short and small/short string optimization (SSO) is applied (usually is by common Standard library implementations from C++11). If lines are long, the space for string is dynamically allocated and each allocation also has some additional memory overhead.
2. You `push_back` these `std::string` objects into a `std::vector`, which typically increase the size of the internal buffer exponentially (such as doubling it when it run out of space). That is why reserving space (`std::vector::reserve`) is used when you know the number of vector elements in advance.

This is the price for such a "comfortable" approach. What might help is to store the whole file contents as a single `std::string` and then store just indexes/pointers into beginnings of individual lines in a separate array/vector (though you then cannot treat these pointers as strings since they won't be null-terminated; or, you can in fact, if you substitute new-line characters by null characters).

In C++17, you can store lines as instances of `std::string_view` to the whole file contents stored in a single `std::string`.

Just note that `std::string_view` will likely by larger than a pointer/index. For instance, with libstdc++ and x86_64, `sizeof(std::string_view)` is 16 bytes, but pointer/index will occupy 8 bytes. And for files smaller than 4 GB, you can even use 32-bit indexes. If you have a lot of lines in processed files, these differences can matter.

**UPDATE**

This question is highly relevant: [C++ Fast way to load large txt file in vector](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52699244/580083).

Comment: I will try to implement these suggestions and accept the answer if it works. If you have an example, mainly for point 2) (i am not sure point 1) will release a lot of memory as I do not have a lot of files), it would be great

Comment: @froz Point 1) might save a lot of memory as well, maybe much more than point 2). I would read whole file into a single `std::string`, substitute new-line-characters by null-characters while counting number of lines, then reserving space for vector indexes using that counter, and finally passing again and storing indexes. These 2 structures (string with file contents and vector of indexes) would be a result of `read_file` function.

Comment: @froz BTW it's not a number of files that matters, it's a number of lines in each file.