# Convert a string with various float numbers into floats.

Tags: c++, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I have a series of strings like this 
"50 50 10"

Each number is supposed to represent the x, y, and z values of an origin. I want to convert each number of this string into an actual float.

I tried using atof, but that gave me back just the first number, 50 in this case.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly)

Answer (score 3):

Use a istringstream,

```
int main() {

    string s = "50 50 50";

    istringstream instream;
    instream.str(s);

    double a, b, c;
    instream >> a >> b >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use the string stream. This site: [has a great tutorial for it.](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/95826-stringstream-tutorial/) It will also allow for direct casting from string to whatever type you need. (In this case float.)