# C++ fast cin input streaming

Tags: c++, scanf, cin

I am attempting the following SPOJ problem. I'd like to clarify that I do not need solution for this problem which is why I have not tagged this question as 'algorithm'.

```
Multiply the given numbers. 

Input
n [the number of multiplications <= 1000]
l1 l2 [numbers to multiply (at most 10000 decimal digits each)]

Output
The results of multiplications.

Time Limit: 2 seconds.
```

I have a naïve solution O(n^2) which is the way we were taught in school (read input as string and do character-wise multiplication). I know I can optimize it further through Karatsuba method.

Question:
My present code is in C++. I have read on the internet that reading through `scanf` is faster than `cin`. Given the input size is so large, does it make a significant difference in such cases?

Given a choice I would not like to mix C with C++, so any ideas on how I can improve my input streaming shall be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: The thing to remember that the problems on sites like SPOJ are very seldom applicable to real-world problems. And that to successfully make programs for these site you have to make some "hacks" that will be looked down upon if used in real-world applications.

Comment: As for this specific case, are you sure it's the input that's the bottleneck, and not the actual calculations?

Comment: Relevant: [Fast text-file reading in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17925143/85371) and [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Honestly, I'm not sure about that. However, I posted this question to help me for future reference as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`sync_with_stdio`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/sync_with_stdio/):

```
cin.sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This will turn off synchronization with cstdio stream and will improve the speed.

[Demo](http://asciinema.org/a/6117)

Comment: I am interested to see if this works for someone else, because it has never seemed to make a difference for me.

Comment: @falsetru: note, your screencast does not demonstrate much because of caching effects. The first time a file is read is always slower (not in cache yet). For a complete demonstration you would need to alternate the measures between with/without a couple times and then take the median or best of each category and compare those. *OT: nice tool!*

Comment: @MatthieuM., Thank you for comment and correction. BTW, I ran multiple times with the same input file before I recorded.

Comment: @falsetru: good :) Then caching should not have affected the result!

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull

Answer (score 0):

While I would never give a blanket statement of performance, on SPOJ (particularly with the Pyramid cluster) I have noticed significant differences between `cin` and `scanf`.

I would use `scanf` if you think I/O is limiting you.

And don't disregard something just because it is available in C (that would be quite a few things!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Slightly off-topic but can you clarify what is Pyramid cluster?

Answer (score -1):

`scanf()` and `printf()` can be used in C++ too. It's not going to **mix** C with C++.
Just include the `<cstdio>` header file.

And of course `scanf()` and `printf()` is a lot faster than `cin` and `cout` respectively.

Comment: Yes, it will mix C and C++ (remember, their standard libraries are part of the language specs). In particular, not using `sync_with_stdio` (as the other answer rightly suggests) will lead to undeterministic results, because of that.

Comment: As C++ library includes all of the header files of C library, so we can use them with C++. Yeah, in this case that's a mix.

Comment: To be clear, I didn't say you "can't mix". You can. Your answer, however, falsely claims "this is not going to mix".

Comment: The problem is not so much using `scanf` or `printf` but rather using `scanf` and `std::cin` OR `printf` and `std::cout`/`std::cerr`. In general the C and C++ libraries have **independent** buffers, thus leading to strange results if they are not sync'ed together (controlled via `sync_with_stdio`).