# Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);

Tags: c++, c

What is the significance of including

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
```

in C++ programs?

In my tests, it speeds up the execution time, but is there a test case I should be worried about by including this?

Do the 2 statements always have to be together, or is the first one sufficient, i.e., ignoring `cin.tie(NULL)`?

Also, is it permissible to use simultaneous C and C++ commands if its value has been set to `false`?

https://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/7316085

The above code worked fine, until I used `scanf/printf` in a C++ program with the value as `true`. In this case, it gave a segmentation fault. What could be the possible explanation for this?

Comment: You actually used that with false . Your code says so???

Answer (score 480, accepted):

The two calls have different meanings that have nothing to do with performance; the fact that *it speeds up the execution time* is (or *might be*) just a side effect. You should understand what each of them does and not blindly include them in every program because they look like an optimization.

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
```

This disables the synchronization between the C and C++ standard streams. By default, all standard streams are synchronized, which in practice allows you to mix C- and C++-style I/O and get sensible and expected results. If you disable the synchronization, then C++ streams are allowed to have their own independent buffers, which makes mixing C- and C++-style I/O an adventure.

Also keep in mind that synchronized C++ streams are thread-safe (output from different threads may interleave, but you get no data races).

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

This unties `cin` from `cout`. Tied streams ensure that one stream is flushed automatically before each I/O operation on the other stream.

By default `cin` is tied to `cout` to ensure a sensible user interaction. For example:

```
std::cout << "Enter name:";
std::cin >> name;
```

If `cin` and `cout` are tied, you can expect the output to be flushed (i.e., visible on the console) before the program prompts input from the user. If you untie the streams, the program might block waiting for the user to enter their name but the "Enter name" message is not yet visible (because `cout` is buffered by default, output is flushed/displayed on the console only on demand or when the buffer is full).

So if you untie `cin` from `cout`, you must make sure to flush `cout` manually every time you want to display something before expecting input on `cin`.

In conclusion, know what each of them does, understand the consequences, and then decide if you really want or need the *possible* side effect of speed improvement.

Comment: When you say "you must make sure to flush cout manually every time you want to display something before expecting input on cin", that can be as simple as appending "... << std::flush" or "... << std::endl" to the end of every line that begins "std::cout << ...", right?

Comment: Yes, it is as simple as that, but be careful with "the end of every line" part. `cout` is buffered for a reason, if you flush it too often, when you don't actually need it, you might see a performance hit.

Comment: @Ionut is there something equivalent to the tie() functionality in C for scanf, printf?

Comment: @iajnr No, not directly. In C, you can either flush manually before `scanf()`, disable buffering completely or switch to line buffering (which should flush after newline or when input is read from `stdin` - see https://linux.die.net/man/3/setlinebuf ).

Comment: At leetcode, it significantly improves runtime, maybe these competitive websites do something special for input tests.

Comment: "Also keep in mind that synchronized C++ streams are thread-safe" so is there an effect of sync_with_stdio(false) on this thread-safety? Only when mixing C and C++ I/O perhaps?

Answer (score 45):

This is to synchronize IOs from C and C++ world. If you synchronize, then you have a guaranty that the orders of all IOs is exactly what you expect. In general, the problem is the buffering of IOs that causes the problem, synchronizing let both worlds to share the same buffers. For example `cout << "Hello"; printf("World"); cout << "Ciao";`; without synchronization you'll never know if you'll get `HelloCiaoWorld` or `HelloWorldCiao` or `WorldHelloCiao`...

`tie` lets you have the guaranty that IOs channels in C++ world are **tied** one to each other, which means for example that every output have been flushed before inputs occurs (think about `cout << "What's your name ?"; cin >> name;`).

You can always mix C or C++ IOs, but if you want some reasonable behavior you must synchronize both worlds. Beware that in general it is not recommended to mix them, if you program in C use C stdio, and if you program in C++ use streams. But you may want to mix existing C libraries into C++ code, and in such a case it is needed to synchronize both.

Comment: Even without syncronization, different calls to `cout <<` cannot change order so `CiaoHelloWorld` is not possible for your example case. Syncronization is strictly about different buffering methods.

Comment: i don't even know if it is true, but I upvoted because of explanation

Answer (score 13):

It's just common stuff for making **cin** input work faster.

For a quick explanation: the first line turns off buffer synchronization between the **cin** stream and C-style **stdio** tools (like scanf or gets) — so **cin** works faster, but you can't use it simultaneously with **stdio** tools.

The second line unties **cin** from **cout** — by default the **cout** buffer flushes each time when you read something from **cin**. And that may be slow when you repeatedly read something small then write something small many times. So the line turns off this synchronization (by literally tying **cin** to **null** instead of **cout**).

Answer (score 6):

Using `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` is sufficient to decouple the `C` and `C++` streams. You can find a discussion of this in [Standard C++ IOStreams and Locales](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321585585), by Langer and Kreft. They note that how this works is implementation-defined.

The `cin.tie(NULL)` call seems to be requesting a decoupling between the activities on `cin` and `cout`. I can't explain why using this with the other optimization should cause a crash. As noted, the link you supplied is bad, so no speculation here.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of great answers. I just want to add a small note about decoupling the stream.

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

I have faced an issue while decoupling the stream with the CodeChef platform. When I submitted my code, the platform response was "Wrong Answer" but after tying the stream and testing the submission. It worked.

So, If anyone wants to untie the stream, the output stream must be flushed.