# Why do the fast IO methods like this, work in c++?

Tags: c++, io, cout

Fast I/O methods like the following are used in C++ for competitive coding, which don't push output to STDIO, and rather keep it in buffer, making I/O much faster than normal cout. Why does this output method work faster than putchar_unlocked() of C? 
(I think that cout uses putchar in background.)

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Who told you that this works "faster". In fact, the end result is likely to be slower, with all the extra flushing and syncing activity.

Comment: *Fast I/O methods like the following are used in C++ for competitive coding* -- So competitive coding is about how fast your output device is instead of how good the algorithm you used to solve the problem is?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, This page is the source: geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-for-competitive-programming/. I have tried these tricks myself on OJs, which give the expected result. (This trick being faster than normal scanf.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, You're right, competitive coding is about good algorithm, but many a few times, IO speed determines which solution is accepted, and which is not, because IO is a slow step.
And, I'm taking about a solution with and without this trick, but with same algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Significance of ios\_base::sync\_with\_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull)