# C++ fastest way to read file line by line

Tags: c++, file-io

I don't want any boost dependency or anything external. I could read the file line by line, and process each line separately. But if it works better, I can also load the whole file in memory, and process it line by line afterwards.

What's the best approach? Also, what is the fastest approach, how do they differ?

Also, this should both work with a regular text file, and piping a file through terminal.

Comment: I found this reference on using ifstream, but without enough details
https://lemire.me/blog/2012/06/26/which-is-fastest-read-fread-ifstream-or-mmap/

Comment: Do you want the best approach or the fastest way? You probably can't have both.

Comment: why do you need to read line by line? Reading all the file contents as a whole and then processing line by line will most likely be faster

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31162367/10077

Comment: @UKMonkey Oh you didn't know? They shouldn't learn, they should just DISAPPEAR from this holy website - Of course I'm kidding. But that's how a big part of SO users behave.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. OP is asking the *fast* way, but the suggested duplicate is about just reading "line by line"...

Answer (score 8):

Just use [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Pretty straightforward solution:

```
std::ifstream file("filePath");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    // line contains the current line
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How would that change if I have to read through pipe, i.e. piping a text file through terminal?

Comment: @BaronYugovich: If you're just piping into stdin, just use something like `std::getline(std::cin, line)`.

Comment: Just FYI, this code itself is far from "fastest". Actually, it is *very slow*. OP is asking the fast way. Since IO takes a long time, one should load as much data as possible into the memory at once.