# Return single integer i.e. value of solve(A) mod 1000000007

Tags: c, algorithm

```
/**
 * @input A : Integer
 * 
 * @Output Integer
 */
int solve(int A){
    int ans,i;
    ans=0;
    i=1;
    while(i<=A){
        ans=((ans+def(i))%1000000007);
        i++;
    }
    return (ans);
}

int def(int m){
    int ans,k;
    ans=1;
    k=1;
    while(k<=m){
        if(gcd(k,m)==1){
            ans=ans*k;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return (ans%m);
}

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b); 
}
```

main function is calling solve function, everything is fine. I just need to reduce the time complexity. For the input A: 114233 The expected output is 902650983, but my program is giving time limit exceeded. Please help. How can I reduce the time complexity in this problem?

Edit:

Actually main function is passing a value A to solve function then question has asked to implement these following functions:

```
Def P(m):
    ans=1
    k=1
    while k<=m:
        if GCD(k,m)==1:
            ans*=k
        k+=1
    return (ans % m)

def F(A):
    ans = 0
    i=1
    while i<=A:
        ans+=P(i)
        i+=1
    return ans % 1000000007
```

Comment: `ans+def(i)` would easily overflow

Comment: of course it is time limit exceeded. if A = 100000, your main solve function will run 100K times, and inside def, it loops again from 1 to 100K. 100K * 100K = surely TLE.

Comment: How can I reduce this? I am stuck here for a long time

Comment: Can you explain what the code is doing?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Please see the updated question. The title of the question is GCD knows no Limit.

Comment: Do some math on the problem's statement. Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Avoid [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) or use [bignum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)s

Comment: and do not use recursion as it definitely does not help with performance

Comment: And: using `for()` loops will make your program more compact, and improve readability.

Comment: @P__J__ recursion does not hurt, as can be verified on godbolt's *Compiler Explorer*. Any half decent compiler is able to convert it into a loop through tail-call optimization.

Comment: The code is wrong. Running it to the end gives results different than what you claim. Replacing `ans=ans*k` with `ans=((long long)ans*k)%1000000007` fixes the overflow, but still does not get the expected result. Replacing `return (ans%m)` with `return ans%1000000007` does not help either. Had I known what you want, I'd be able to do something like: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51776619/4955498

Comment: @MichaelVeksler one trivial example does not proof your very strong opinion. Compilers may in some circumstances convert it. But the key here is : **in some circumstances**. Recursion in most cases hurts the performance and safety of the code, and is barred in many industrial standards (MISRA for example)  Should be avoided.

Comment: @P__J__ we are not talking about theoretical code, but about the `gcd` code above. And it is impossible to generalize, since sometimes recursion is faster and sometimes it is slower. Recursion can be faster, e.g., when performing an operation on all nodes of a balanced binary-search-tree (without pointers to parents), is much faster with recursion.  Recursion can be slower or troublesome (due to stack depth limit) on many other problems. There is no general rule, and this has to be examined on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler ok. discussion is pointless. As I wrote recursion is dangerous and banned in many standards. Usually is also slower. BTW please  provide the benchmark which proofs this better recursion performance.

Comment: @P__J__, I was not able to send a direct message with a benchmark. Look at https://godbolt.org/z/yz5pzV  , on wandbox.org the iterative code runs almost 10% slower, and is much more complex. It is possible to add another pointer to the structure (pointing to parent), but I specifically stated that the data has no pointer to parent in the problem requirement. In this case, recursion wins both on simplicity and speed. My point is, over-generalization is not doing any good, and things have to be examined on a case-by-case basis.