# How to avoid overlaps between int(xxx)_t, and make my code correct?

Tags: c++

I want to make in/out functions not to write format specifiers many times. (I don't want to use cin/cout functions as possible, because they run slowly.)

So, I write this code.

If there are "int_fast16_t i" and "string s," I expect: {scanf(%d, i); cin >> s;} == {in() >> i >> s;}

```
struct in
{
    template<typename typ> in& operator>>(typ& val) { std::cin >> val; return *this; }
    in& operator>>(char& val) { std::scanf(" %c", &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::int_fast8_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNdFAST8, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::uint_fast8_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNuFAST8, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::int_fast16_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNdFAST16, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::uint_fast16_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNuFAST16, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::int_fast32_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNdFAST32, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::uint_fast32_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNuFAST32, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::int_fast64_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNdFAST64, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(std::uint_fast64_t& val) { std::scanf("%" SCNuFAST64, &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(float& val) { std::scanf("%f", &val); return *this; }
    in& operator>>(double& val) { std::scanf("%lf", &val); return *this; }
};

struct out
{
    template<typename typ> template<> out& operator<<(typ& val) { std::cout << val; return *this; }
    out& operator<<(char& val) { std::printf("%c", val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::int_fast8_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIdFAST8, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::uint_fast8_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIuFAST8, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::int_fast16_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIdFAST16, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::uint_fast16_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIuFAST16, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::int_fast32_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIdFAST32, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::uint_fast32_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIuFAST32, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::int_fast64_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIdFAST64, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(std::uint_fast64_t& val) { std::printf("%" PRIuFAST64, val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(float& val) { std::printf("%f", val); return *this; }
    out& operator<<(double& val) { std::printf("%lf", val); return *this; }
};
```

However, it causes errors.

```
error: 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast32_t&)' cannot be overloaded with 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast16_t&)'
note: previous declaration 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast16_t&)'
error: 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast32_t&)' cannot be overloaded with 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast16_t&)'
note: previous declaration 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast16_t&)'
error: 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast64_t&)' cannot be overloaded with 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast16_t&)'
note: previous declaration 'in& in::operator>>(int_fast16_t&)'
error: 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast64_t&)' cannot be overloaded with 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast16_t&)'
note: previous declaration 'in& in::operator>>(uint_fast16_t&)'   ...(other similar error)
```

Are int_fast16_t, int_fast32_t and int_fast64_t the same? If so, what should I rewrite to make correct functions?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull) is the better alternative?

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the various `int_fastNN_t` are implementation-specific typedefs that may map to the same thing so cannot be used for overloads.

Instead you should overload on the fundamental types `signed char`, `short int`, `int`, `long int`, `long long int` and the equivalent unsigned ones.

Comment: I hear that bits of 'int' depends on application execution environment, so I want to use 'int_fastNN_t'. Is there a way to implement it using "a"?

Comment: You should *define* your overloads based on the fundamental types, but you can *call* them with the `int_fastNN_t` types. The compiler will map `int_fastNN_t` to whatever the appropriate type is and pick the appropriate overload.

Comment: @underscore -- to be clear: the `int_xxx_t` types are all **typedefs** for built-in types. As long as you've overloaded for all the built-in types, the `int_xxx_t` types are all covered.

Comment: @Pete Becker That makes sense. Thanks :)