# C++ Code showing weird behavior while running

Tags: c++

I have written a simple code in C++. But suddenly i got one weird behavior by the output of my code. I am not getting why i am getting this type of problem here.

Below is My Simple C++ Code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int lli;
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);

    cout<<"Hi\n";
    lli a[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

    cout<<"Original Array : ";
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
    cout<<a[i]<<" ";

    lli q;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter q : ";
    cin>>q;

    cout<<"q = "<<q<<"\n";
}
```

The weird behavior is this : Whenever i am running my code. It is not printing any output message "Hi..and all". It seems it is directly asking for the input of used "q" variable ( below ) first. Then it is printing the required output. I am very much confused by this behavior. Please tell me why my code is asking for the input of q first. And then it is showing original behavior.

Below is the output of my code :

[image]

Note : Whenever i am removing these three lines :

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
cout.tie(NULL);
```

It is behaving perfectly as required. I am not getting Why.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull

Comment: you should read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31165481/11630848

Comment: Why did you put those lines there? What were you trying to do?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/560648)

Comment: In fact, overall this question is a great example of why you should not copy/paste competition-related "optimisations" without actually understanding what they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause is `cin.tie(NULL);`. It means that you de-synchronize console input with output. This means that console output appears as late as possible (when the program ends). Normally the output buffer is flushed (displayed) whenever there is an input operation pending, however by using `cin.tie(NULL);` you explicitly say that you don't want this to happen.

Answer (score 3):

C++ output streams are buffered.  When you write to `std::cout`, the data is stored in memory, and will only be passed to the output device when the buffer fills up or the stream is explicitly `flush`ed.  The output you send to `std::cout` won't appear on the screen until one of those conditions occurs.  This is done to improve performance, since I/O operations are very slow compared to writing to memory.

By default, `std::cout` is tied to `std::cin` as if `std::cin.tie(&std::cout)` had been called.  This means that before `std::cin` does any read operation, it will automatically call `std::cout.flush()`.  This is a useful default, since it ensures that any prompt you wrote to `std::cout` will appear before `std::cin` blocks waiting for input.  By calling `std::cin.tie(NULL)`, you have explicitly opted to turn off this feature, so it's up to you to ensure you call `std::cout.flush()` explicitly before you read from `std::cin` to ensure the buffered data has been written to the terminal.