# adding some C++ to a library used by C programs?

Tags: c++, c, linker, compatibility

I have a long-standing C library used by C and C++ programs.

It has a few compilation units (in other words, C++ source files) that are totally C++, but this has never been a problem.  My understanding is that linkers (at least, Linux, Windows, etc.) always work at the file-by-file level so that an object file in a library that isn't referred to, doesn't have any effect on the linking, isn't put in the binary, and so on.  The C users of the library never refer to the C++ symbols, and the library doesn't internally, so the resulting linked app is C-only.  So while it's always worked perfectly, I don't know if it's because the C++ doesn't make it past the linking stage, or because more deeply, this kind of mixing would always work even if I *did* mix languages.

For the first time I'm thinking of adding some C++ code to the existing C API's implementation.

For purposes of discussion let us say I have a C function that does something, and logs it via `stdout`, and since this is buffered separately from `cout`, the output can become confusing.  So let us say this module has an option that can be set to log to `cout` instead of `stdout`.  (This is a more general question, not merely about getting `cout` and `stdout` to cooperate.)  The C++ code might or might not run, but the dependencies will definitely be there.

In what way would this impact users of this library?  It is widely used so I cannot check with the entire user base, and as it's used for mission-critical apps it'd be unacceptable to make a change that makes links start failing, at least unless I supply a release note explaining the problem and solution.

Just as an example of a possible problem, I know compilers have "hidden" libraries of support functions that are necessary for C and C++ programs.  There are obviously also the Standard C and C++ libraries, that normally you don't have to explicitly link to.  My concerns are that the compiler might not know to do these things.

Comment: "let us say". That is not a good way to explain what you are trying to do. There are too many generalities and unclear points in your description. Please construct a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that illustrates the concepts and problems that you are trying to understand or solve.

Comment: By default `cin` and `cout` synchronize with good ol' C IO. They had to because if you're calling C libraries, and you do fairly frequently, things will get messy. In fact there is a cargo cult that reflexively turns off this synchronization. See [Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull) for details if you are interested.

Comment: Is the library linked statically (to `.a` or `.lib`) or dynamically (to `.so` or `.dll` or `.dylib`)?

Comment: I'm using it on Linux as a .a and .so, and on Windows as a .lib and .dll .

Comment: _By default cin and cout synchronize with good ol' C IO._ -- to be clear this has nothing to do with cin or cout.  As to a test case, I really couldn't have been clearer that my worry isn't to show I have a problem in a specific case (which I could give you a test example for) but rather to know a priori that there are no cases where it would fail.  Unless you want me to generate all possible programs, I don't see how I can give you that as a test suite.