# Concert Tickets, sorting and searching problem

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, search

*There are n concert tickets available, each with a certain price. Then, m customers arrive, one after another.
Each customer announces the maximum price he or she is willing to pay for a ticket, and after this, they will get a ticket with the nearest possible price such that it does not exceed the maximum price.*

**Input**

```
The first input line contains integers n and m: the number of tickets and the number of customers.

The next line contains n integers h1,h2,…,hn: the price of each ticket.

The last line contains m integers t1,t2,…,tm: the maximum price for each customer.
```

**Output**

```
Print, for each customer, the price that they will pay for their ticket. After this, the ticket cannot be purchased again.

If a customer cannot get any ticket, print −1.
```

**Constraints**

```
 1 ≤ n, m ≤ 2⋅10^5

 1 ≤ hi, ti ≤ 10^9
```

**Example**

```
Input:
5 3
5 3 7 8 5
4 8 3

Output:
3
8
-1
```

My approach is to sort all h1, h2, ... hn
then use binary search for each ti and will mark the chosen h as inf. this will be roughly done in nlog(n) + mlog(n). Is there any better idea to do it.

I implemented the code as:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    cout.tie(NULL);
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<ll> v(n);
    ll p;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> p;
        if (p < v.front())
            cout << -1 << "\n";
        else
        {   if(p>v.back()){
            cout<<v.back()<<"\n";
            v.pop_back();
        }else{
            auto it = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), p);
            cout << *(it-1) << "\n";
            v.erase(it - 1);
        }
        }
    }
}
```

it is not executing in the limited time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using a data structure like [`tree map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html).

For each fixed price of ticket i.e. `h[i]` put them in a tree map with the count as value.
Tree map ensures the keys inserted are in order.
So for example, for the input in question, the map will look like :

```
3 -> 1
5 -> 2
7 -> 1
8 -> 1
```

Then in this map, search for the user's bid using binary search on the tree map's key set.

In Java's treemap you could use [`floorKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorKey-K-) method to get the ***greatest key in the map less than or equal to the key you are looking for***. The time complexity is `O(log(n))` for this method because treemap in Java uses a Red Black Tree implementation.

Once you find a key, decrease its value by 1, if its value is 0 remove the key.

Do this with each user's bid. Overall time complexity is `O(nlog(n))`.

Code in java would be ( not tested ) :

```
private int[] getUserPrices(int[] prices, int[] bids) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Integer> tree = new TreeMap<>();
    for ( int price : prices ) {
      if ( tree.containsKey(price) ) {
         tree.put(price, tree.get(price) + 1);
      } else {
         tree.put(price, 1);
      }
    }

    int[] result = new int[bids.length];
    for ( int i = 0; i < bids.length; i++ ) {
       Integer k = tree.floorKey(bids[i]);
       if ( k != null ) {
          result[i] = k;
          int value = tree.get(k);
          if ( value-1 > 0 ) {
            tree.put(k, value-1);
          } else {
            tree.remove(k);
          }
       } else {
         result[i] == -1;
       }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tree maps are a good solution but it does feel a little bit overkill, I am assuming this guy is still a beginner and it will take a lot more than a few sentences to explain to him what a tree map is....

Answer (score 1):

In your approach, the time complexity is O(n^2) in the worst case, because of the line

```
v.erase(it - 1);
```

Here is a better approach

```
int main()
{
    int n, m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    int x;
    set<array<int, 2>> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        s.insert({x, i});
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        cin >> x;
        auto it = s.lower_bound({x + 1, 0});
        if (it != s.begin())
        {
            it--;
            cout << (*it)[0] << "\n";
            s.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "-1\n";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

You can use sets in this case, for better time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

For **JAVA** readers...

```
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scn.nextInt();
        int m = scn.nextInt();
        TreeMap<Long, Integer> prices = new TreeMap<>();
        long[] bids = new long[m];

        for (int l = 0; l < n; l++) {     // filling the TreeMap
            long price = scn.nextLong();
            if (prices.containsKey(price)) {
                prices.put(price, prices.get(price) + 1);
            } else {
                prices.put(price, 1);
            }
        }
        for (int l = 0; l < m; l++) {     // Calculating Answer for each query
            bids[l] = scn.nextLong();
            Long answer = prices.floorKey(bids[l]);
            if (answer != null) {
                int val = prices.get(answer);
                if (val > 1) {
                    prices.put(answer, val - 1);
                    System.out.println(answer);
                } else {
                    prices.remove(answer);
                    System.out.println(answer);
                }

            } else {
                System.out.println(-1);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

here is the solutioin using **"multiset"**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define endl '\n'
using namespace std;
void solve()

{
    int n,m;
    cin>>n>>m;
    multiset<int>a;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int temp;
        cin>>temp;
        a.insert(temp);
    }
    while (m--)
    {
        int t;
        cin>>t;
        auto it=a.upper_bound(t);
        if(it==a.begin())
        {
            cout<<"-1"<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<*(--it)<<endl;
            a.erase(it);
        }
    }
    
    return ;
}
int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(nullptr);
    int tt=1;
    // cin>>tt;
    while(tt--)
    {
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your posted code is **dreadful**! (1) See: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) (2) `#define endl '\n'` - really? When the `std::` namespace has an `endl` in it already? (3) Care to explain what `ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(nullptr);` is doing, and why OP should use such trickery?

Comment: @AdrianMole the code posted is just for an idea how multisets is used to solve the problem.
(1). '#include<bits/stdc++.h>' is used  as **cses** accepted the code pasted without throwing a **TLE**.
(2) [CF blog](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/63913),[GFG](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/endl-vs-n-in-cpp/#:~:text=endl%20vs%20%5Cn%20in%20C%2B%2B,-View%20Discussion&text=endl%20and%20%5Cn%20both%20seem,just%20inserts%20a%20new%20line.&text=It%20is%20a%20manipulator.)
(3) refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull).