# Syncing with stdio is making program i/o non - interactive?

Tags: c++, io, stl, legacy-code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    cout << "Print two numbers: ";
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << x << y;
    
    return 0;
}

Input : 23 24 

Output : Print two numbers: 2324
```

> Here before printing the line  "**Print two numbers**: " on console, stdin
> is waiting for x and y, then prints the entire output on console as
> given above.

> **After removing sync lines from above code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    // ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    // cin.tie(0);

    cout << "Print two numbers: ";
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    cout << x << y;
    
    return 0;
}
```

> Here first it's printing line "**Print two numbers:** " on console then
> stdin stream is waiting for x and y.

I am unable to understand this behaviour.

Comment: This behavior is unrelated to syncing with stdio. You changed two lines in your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Significance of ios\_base::sync\_with\_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik, link helped.

Answer (score 2):

By default, `cin` is tied to `cout`, so operations on those streams are in the order they are written in the program.

However, doing `cin.tie(0)` will untie `cin` from `cout`, so operations on `cout` and `cin` may be interspersed.

Note that all operations on any one stream will still be in the order they are written in the program.