# Fast input/output for Competitive Programming

Tags: c++

I see people using this snippet extensively for achieving fast i/o in competitive programming

```
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
```

Though i understand what it does mostly from here :

[Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull)

I want to know why this statement is not included

```
cout.tie(NULL);
```

i.e" What difference does this make to the program or does this achieve the same objective as that of

```
cin.tie(NULL);
```

Also is it necessary to use NULL or false instead of 0 and 1.

Comment: I would venture that just using C-style I/O would be simpler than trying to get C++ iostreams to be performant...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you can see in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/G57Tdv) example and in the [docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie), `std::cin` and `std::cerr` are both tied to `std::cout` by default, but the relationship is one-way.  There is no need to call `cout.tie(NULL)` because the tied stream is already `nullptr`.  The statement would have no effect.

You would not be able to use an argument of `1`; `tie` takes a pointer to a `std::ostream`.  `0`/`NULL`/`false` all work to untie the streams due to implicit conversions, but to tie two streams together, you would need something like `std::cout.tie(&std::cerr)`.

Answer (score 6):

`cout` is tied to `cin`, not the other way around.

`cout` being tied to `cin` means `cout` is flushed automatically when reading from `cin`.

`cout.tie(nullptr);` would be pointless, as `cout.tie()` is already `nullptr`.

---

`NULL` is an equivalent of `0`. The C++ type-safe way to express a null pointer is `nullptr`.