# Why does function that takes parameter as vector returns a garbage value?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool compare(string a, string b) {
    return a < b;
}

int B_SEARCH(vector<string>::iterator ARR, int START, int END, string TARGET) {
    if (START > END)
        return 0;

    int MIDDLE = (START + END) / 2;

    cout << "CURRENT MIDDLE: " << MIDDLE << "\n";

    if (ARR[MIDDLE] == TARGET) {
        cout << "ARR[MIDDLE]: " << ARR[MIDDLE] << " "
             << "TARGET: " << TARGET << " And MIDDLE is: " << MIDDLE << "\n";
        return MIDDLE;
    } else if (ARR[MIDDLE] < TARGET)
        B_SEARCH(ARR, MIDDLE + 1, END, TARGET);
    else
        B_SEARCH(ARR, START, MIDDLE - 1, TARGET);
}

int main() {
    cin.tie(0);
    cout.tie(0);
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);

    int N, M, cnt = 0;

    cin >> N >> M;

    vector<string> ARR;
    vector<string> ANSWER;
    ARR.reserve(N);

    string temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> temp;
        ARR.push_back(temp);
    }

    vector<string>::iterator BEGIN = ARR.begin();
    vector<string>::iterator END = ARR.end();

    sort(BEGIN, END, compare);

    for (int i = 0, gbg; i < M; i++) {
        cin >> temp;
        if (gbg = B_SEARCH(BEGIN, 0, ARR.size() - 1, temp)) {
            cout << "B_SEARCH: " << gbg << "\n";
            ANSWER.push_back(temp);
            cnt++;
        }
    }

    cout << cnt << '\n';

    if (cnt)
        for (int i = 0; i < ANSWER.size(); i++)
            cout << ANSWER[i] << '\n';
}
```

This is a code that takes 2 integer as input and store value to `N` and `M` and repeat `N` times to get inputs as string to store them in vector array,
repeat `M` times more to check whether each input string is matched to string vectors array.

If I give inputs as

```
3 4
ohhe
charlie
base
obama
base
ohhe
clinton
```

Then `ohhe`,`charlie`,`base` will stored in vector array,
and tries to find `obama`,`base`,`ohhe`,`clinton` string is in string vector.
( I know it's confusing but I can't find better example to explain my situation :( )

After I run the code, I've realized that function `B_SEARCH` returns a memory address(maybe garbage value) instead of given `MIDDLE` variable's value.

To show some of by output, it would be like...

```
CURRENT MIDDLE: 1
CURRENT MIDDLE: 0
ARR[MIDDLE]: base TARGET: base AND MIDDLE is: 0
B_SEARCH: 6422116
```

I've wrote some letters for debug, and **third line of output says `MIDDLE` which is return value is `0` but if I check the return value in main function, it says `6422116`**

How this happen...? I've never seen error like this.
Is it because of I've gave function's parameter as vector?

Comment: Turn warnings on.

Comment: The only meaningful warning I see is "control reaches end of non-void function". But I'm sure `B_SEARCH` always reaches to its end

Comment: But that doesn't seem to be the case. The only branch you're returning from is the first `if`. You should be *returning* the result of the recursive calls to `B_SEARCH`.

Comment: I do have second return branch for `if(ARR[MIDDLE] == TARGET)` where returns `MIDDLE`. First branch is just for explicitly show the exit status.

Comment: OHHH I get it now. I have to add `return` to those two recursive call right?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation. Have a great day

Comment: Have a look at [Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31162367/3422102) and make sure you really want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Fix it by returning the value in your binary search recursive function, type is int but you use it like a void function:

```cpp
return B_SEARCH(ARR, MIDDLE + 1, END, TARGET);
    else
      return  B_SEARCH(ARR, START, MIDDLE - 1, TARGET);
}
```

In recursive function you must always return value else there is no purpose for the operation!

PS: Also a `while` iterative would become an `if` in a recursive function