# Can't convert string to int c++

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple number reverse program and I've tried many different ways to convert the string to an int but all I get is errors or "core dumped" while executing or compiling. I'm new to C++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

void solve(){
    string n, ans=""; 
    cin >> n; 

    for(int i=0; i<n.length()+1;++i){
        ans += n[n.length()-i];
    }
    int num = stoi(ans);

    cout << ans << "\n";
} 
int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);

    int t;
    cin >>t;

    while(t--){
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How does repeatedly adding the last character of `n` into `ans` solve your problem? What is that supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik OP is appending the `n.length()-i` element (not the last each time, as `i` changes). But therein lies the problem, on the first loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop is accessing an out-of-bounds element of the `n` string on its first iteration: when `i` is zero, you are attempting to access the `n.length()` element of `n` but the last element is at position `n.length() - 1`. Remember that arrays, strings and other 'containers' in C++ start at element `0` and end at element `n-1` – where `n` is the size (length) of the container.

You can fix this by starting your loop with `i = 1` rather than with `i = 0`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::string;
using std::cout, std::cin; // Pre C++17, you'll need 2 separate "using" statements.

void solve()
{
    string n, ans = "";
    cin >> n;
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n.length(); ++i) {
        ans += n[n.length() - i];
    }
    int num = stoi(ans);
    cout << num << "\n"; // I've changed to print "num" rather than "ans"
}

int main()
{
//  For someone who is "new to C++," the following two lines are probably overkill...
//  std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
//  cin.tie(NULL);
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        solve();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) and [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)

On the issue I've commented as "overkill," see: [Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31162367/10871073) (especially the top/accepted answer).

Comment: thank you for your answers and the tip

Comment: @Adrian You're very welcome. You may also like to use the functions provided by the STL. `std::reverse(n.begin(), n.end());` will reverse your string *in place*. [Link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse)