# about a sync_with_stdio(0); and cin.tie(0); please help me

Tags: c++

I have see many people #include<bits/stdc++.h>
and use ios::sync_with_stdio(0); and cin.tie(0);
I don't know what's that
please help me ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Significance of ios\_base::sync\_with\_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162367/significance-of-ios-basesync-with-stdiofalse-cin-tienull)

Comment: *I have see many people #include<bits/stdc++.h>* -- Stop looking at that code.  It is very poor code that is being submitted to an "online competition" coding website. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)