# C++: How to read from a custom text file based on position/length of fields (no delimiter)?

Tags: c++, inputstream, stringstream

I am new to C++, and have some issues reading from a custom text file.

Suppose each line of the file includes the fields EXACTLY with the following format:

- A float starting at position 0, with length 6
- An integer starting at position 6, with length 2
- A string starting at position 8, with length 4
- An integer starting at position 12, with length 3

Note that there is no whitespace (or any other delimiter) between the fields.
But their position and max length are determined.
Here is two lines from a sample file:

```
13.33456Text-13
 3.123 3txt  23
```

Which should be extracted this way (i.e., stored in separate variables):

```
13.334  56  Text  -13
 3.123   3  txt    23
```

Here is the way I am currently implementing it via `string.substr()` method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double f1;
    int d1, d2;
    string str;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Input/TestText01.txt");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        string line;

        while (getline(fin, line))
        {
            f1  = stod(line.substr(0, 6));
            d1  = stoi(line.substr(6, 2));
            str = line.substr(8, 4);
            d2  = stoi(line.substr(12, 3));

            // Do whatever with the extracted data
        }
        cout << "Reached end of file" << endl;
        fin.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Error! File did not open successfully" << endl;
}
```

But I guess using `substr` (with `stod/stoi`) is not optimized, since my input files might be very large.
However, simply extracting from a `stringstream` is not possible here (due to lack of delimiter):

```
stringstream ss{ line };
ss >> f1 >> d1 >> str >> d2;  // does not work
```

So, what is the best way to accomplish this task?
Giving an explanation alongside some sample code will be appreciated.
Please also give me some hints for exception handling in case of a corrupted file (i.e., a file with wrong structure).

Comment: Your way of solving the problem is already good and I don't think that it can be significantly improved. Regarding handling exceptions in the case of a corrupted file: If something goes wrong, do you want your program to immediately terminate with an error message? Or do you only want to print a warning message that specifies that processing one line failed, and then the program should continue by processing the next line?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Thanks. So, finding a way to sweep/scan a stream at each line to successively extract fields one after another won't increase the performance? Regarding the exception handling, I need the latter (inform the user that this line is failed, and then proceed with the next line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way of solving the problem is already good and I don't think that it can be significantly improved.

One micro-optimization that you could do is the following: So that you don't have to copy the strings, you could use the functions [`std::strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) and [`std::strtod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtof) directly on the input string returned by `std::getline`. However, those two functions require a terminating null character. You could temporarily overwrite the first character of the next field with such a null character and, when you are finished, you can restore that character to its original value. However, I doubt that this optimization would be worth the effort, because it would sacrifice code clarify for a very minor performance increase.

You will probably have more success in increasing performance by configuring the C++ standard library in such a way that it is optimized for performance instead of compatibility with the streams of the C standard library. See these questions for further information:

- [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9371238/12149471)
- [Significance of ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false); cin.tie(NULL);](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31162367/12149471)

Regarding handling exceptions in the case of a corrupted file:

The functions [`std::string::substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) can throw exceptions of type [`std::invalid_argument`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument) and exceptions of type [`std::out_of_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range). Both of these types are derived from the class [`std::logic_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error). Therefore, if you want to skip the current line, print an error message and continue with the next line when such an exception is thrown, I recommend that you enclose the 4 lines of the loop in a [`try`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/try_catch)/`catch` block which catches exceptions of type `std::logic_error`, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double f1;
    int d1, d2;
    string str;

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("Input/TestText01.txt");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        string line;

        while (getline(fin, line))
        {
            try
            {
                f1  = stod(line.substr(0, 6));
                d1  = stoi(line.substr(6, 2));
                str = line.substr(8, 4);
                d2  = stoi(line.substr(12, 3));
            }
            catch ( const std::logic_error &e )
            {
                cout << "Skipping line due to invalid input!\n";
                continue;
            }

            // Do whatever with the extracted data
        }
        cout << "Reached end of file" << endl;
        fin.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "Error! File did not open successfully\n" << endl;
}
```