# Read Text file using Boost mmap

Tags: file, boost, iostream, mmap

I am reading the following file:

---

**File.txt**

> Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux Assurance
>   2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\018-1-R.xml  Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux
>   Assurance 2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\A018-2-R.xml 
>   Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux Assurance
>   2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\021-1-R.xml  Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux
>   Assurance 2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\A021-2-R.xml 
>   Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux Assurance
>   2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\022-1-R.xml  Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux
>   Assurance 2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\022-2-R.xml 
>   Y:\Test\DOCUMENTS\DOCUMENTS\Flux Assurance
>   2\multi\ACTEPROC_OK\025-1-R.xml

---

**Source code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/stream.hpp>

std::vector<string> readFile(string);

int main()
{
    std::vector<string> res = readFile("file.txt");
    return 0;
}

std::vector<string> readFile(string f)
{
    boost::iostreams::stream<boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source> str(f);
    std::vector<string> app;
    for(string x; str >> x;)
    {
        app.push_back(x);
    }
    return app;
}//end
```

---

**Problem:**

Since There is a space Between **Flux** and **Assurance 2**, it considers **space** as a  separator.

How can remove the separator, or explicitly identify what the separator is?

Comment: Add solutions as answers. That's why they're called answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to with boost or memorymapping.

Firstly

```
str.unsetf(std::ios::skipws);
```

will prevent whitespace from being used as delimiter/skipped.

Secondly, I ***think*** (you don't mention any of that) you wanted to read by line:

```
for(std::string x; std::getline(str, x, '\n');)
{
    app.push_back(x);
}
```

As you can see you can already specify the delimiter.

Lastly, consider using a parser generator. See e.g. here:

- [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702)

Which contains an example that uses Boost Spirit to parse from a memory-mapped file.

Comment: thank you. Yes I actually found a close solution to yours. I don't know if it's interesting. I'll also add it to my question. Thank you