# Efficiently read a portion of text in C++

Tags: c++, boost, text

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21431518/read-text-file-using-boost-mmap) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702) questions about how to efficiently read big amount of text (floats in the second question) in C++ exploiting the `boost::spirit` library.

From what I've seen, the solutions proposed in the questions above read the *whole* text, while I need to read a *portion* of the input text (for example from char x to char y).

Can I exploit the library above for this purpose? How could I efficiently do it otherwise?

Comment: So, you know an offset into the file, and you want to read from that offset to another offset? And how big is that chunk?

Comment: Exactly. However, this is needed for a map/reduce parallel project, so each chunk could be in the order of GBs.

Comment: Single GB or "hundreds of GB"? Also, is the file bigger than your machine's memory?

Comment: You're absolutely right, sorry for my lack of description. However at most 10GBs (since my machine's memory is 12GBs).

Comment: So my personal approach would be to `mmap` at the `startOffset`, with size of `(endOffset - startOffset)` [or the corresponding Windows functionality].

Comment: I didn't know that you could use `mmap` for a subportion of a file. However I hope that this feature is available for an Intel Xeon phi enviroment too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to map a subsection of the file, because mmap just virtually maps memory blocks. Actual pages are only loaded on demand, so you could *map* the full 12GiB of a file even if you have only, say, 4GiB of physical RAM (not even requiring swap).

If your file is text-bases, you will want to find the start-of-line from a random location in the file.

An example of something similar is in the second approach here: [Using boost::iostreams::mapped_file_source with std::multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217301/using-boostiostreamsmapped-file-source-with-stdmultimap/28220864#28220864)

Comment: With the *enormous* caveat that mapping the entire file is only safe on 64 bit architectures, and some would say that not mapping the exact portion you need when that is a well defined and known subset is sloppy programming.

Comment: And some would say that's not an enormous caveat ;)

Comment: It's safe everywhere. It just might not work everywhere

Comment: No, it's not safe everywhere. As I know you know sehe, if you claim all the big contiguous chunks of address space on 32 bit leaving just little fragments between DLLs etc, you can get some very weird and unpredictable errors and failures not just in your own code but in the OS code. Essentially running out of address space is as buggy and unpredictable as running out of memory is - most code, including OS code, doesn't cope well with it happening due to a lack of testing/who cares/it's easily avoidable anyway.

Comment: @NiallDouglas sinds like a reasonable thing to happen. It's just out of memory really. I wonder what OS would cope so badly. Sounds like a reasonable motive to map sub regions indeed

Comment: I've experienced the problem on Windows, Linux and QNX :). Unfortunately ENOMEM is not consistently returned and therefore behaviour is not consistent either, I've seen EINVAL, EAGAIN, and a few others. I think OS devs just decided it wasn't worth the debugging effort given 64 bit makes the problem go away permanently.

Comment: No problem folks: this is a Xeon phi/64 bit dedicated project.