# Efficient parsing of std::stringstream data into std::vector<std::vector<double>>

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I am parsing a data stream of pairs of double values into std::vector>. I use boost as I think it is more efficient. My code is as follow.

```
                std::stringstream tmp_stream;                
                typedef double data_type;            
                typedef ::std::vector < data_type > V_d;
                // type below describes type of the container of all data
                typedef ::std::vector < V_d > V_v_d;
                // list container 
                //typedef ::std::list < V_d > V_v_d;

                V_v_d data;

                ::data_parser::Data_parser < V_v_d > data_parser;
                data_parser ( tmp_stream, data );
```

My input text file is formatted as
{ (132.181,0.683431),
  (136.886,0.988517),
  (137.316,0.504297),
  (133.653,0.602269),
  (150.86,0.236839)
 }
The pairs are not parsed correctly and I received empty pair. What could be the problem? 
Thanks

Comment: You're going to have to show us your data_parser code.

Comment: Why not use std::pair<data_type,data_type>?

Comment: Not sure it relates to the question, but if you will always be working with pairs of doubles, it would probably be much more efficient to use `std::vector<std::pair<double,double> >` for the storage.

Comment: Not sure what code is doing the string -> float conversion, but I recommend using the Intel Numeric String Conversion library, if you're on Intel: http://software.intel.com/en-us/node/485147

Comment: Are you skipping all the other stuff like `(,{})`? If you use an `istringstream` and try to extract those characters into a `double`, weird stuff may happen. Also, do as the previous commenters suggested and use a `std::pair` to store the pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a bit of Boost Spirit, you can use a single line:

```
if (tmp_stream >> std::noskipws >> 
       qi::phrase_match((+qi::double_) % qi::eol, qi::blank, data))
{
```

and another single line to display the results as a bonus:

```
    std::cout << karma::format((karma::double_ % ", ") % karma::eol, data) << "\n";
}
```

**Note** It handles `inf`, `-inf`, `nan` :)

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b6a3591890badff8)**:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> data;

    std::stringstream tmp_stream(
            "123 45 inf -inf nan .7e-99\n"
            "42\n"
            "-1");

    if (tmp_stream >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match((+qi::double_) % qi::eol, qi::blank, data))
    {
        std::cout << karma::format((karma::double_ % ", ") % karma::eol, data) << "\n";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** Slightly adapted to your input grammar, I'd suggest parsing into a vector of pairs instead:

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp> // handle std::pair
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi_match.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<double, double>> data;

    std::stringstream tmp_stream("{ (132.181,0.683431), (136.886,0.988517), (137.316,0.504297), (133.653,0.602269), (150.86,0.236839) }");

    if (tmp_stream >> std::noskipws >> qi::phrase_match(
                   '{' 
                >> 
                     ( '(' >> qi::double_ >> "," >> qi::double_ >> ')' )
                     % ','
                >> '}',
                qi::space, data))
    {
        std::cout << karma::format(karma::delimit(" ") [karma::auto_] % karma::eol, data) << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints: (see **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ede6e22734b2f66)**

```
132.181 0.683 
136.886 0.989 
137.316 0.504 
133.653 0.602 
150.86 0.237
```

**Note** To make things quicker, consider not parsing form a stream, but using

- `streambuf_iterator`
- the underlying byte data if you have it in memory anyways

Comment: About the performance of the above: [How to parse space-separated floats in C++ quickly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465061/how-to-parse-space-separated-floats-in-c-quickly/17479702#17479702) contains benchmarks