# Why mesh python code slower than decomposed one?

Tags: python, performance

I've discovered surprising python behaviour while had investigating thread [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python).

If I run simple python code from that thread

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys


count = 0
start_time = time.time()

for line in sys.stdin:
    count += 1

delta_sec = time.time() - start_time
if delta_sec >= 0:
    lines_per_sec = int(round(count/delta_sec))
    print("Read {0:n} lines in {1:.2f} seconds. LPS: {2:n}".format(count, delta_sec, lines_per_sec))
```

it works with speed 11.5M LPS, and when I decompose the whole script into single function

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sys


def test(input):
    count = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    for line in input:
        count += 1

    delta_sec = time.time() - start_time
    if delta_sec >= 0:
        lines_per_sec = int(round(count/delta_sec))
        print("Read {0:n} lines in {1:.2f} seconds. LPS: {2:n}".format(count, delta_sec, lines_per_sec))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test(sys.stdin)
```

code speeds up to 23M LPS.

Why this simple refactoring makes my code 2 times faster?

*I've run my tests with python2.7 on Ubuntu 13.10.*

Comment: try `input =sys.stdin  for line in input: ...` in your first script

Comment: this method doesn't speeds up first script

Comment: @Leonardo.Z: Shouldn't matter. The attribute lookup only happens once.

Comment: I tried your examples on CPython 2.7, Windows Server 2008 R2 and could not reproduce this behavior. LPS is about the same for both variants. I do not know the reason for your observations and cannot even make an "educated guess"

Comment: @Thorsten Kranz I can suggest that reading from file is too slow on your setup to observe difference between local/global lookups. Do you have the same LPS after changing 'sys.stdin'/'input' to xrange(10**8)?

Comment: You're right, when changing stdin to xrange, I also have a factor 2 (even 2.5) between these two versions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Watching into bytecode helped me to answer this question.
Byte code for working part of the first script is:

```
 10          58 SETUP_LOOP              27 (to 88)
             61 LOAD_NAME                3 (sys)
             64 LOAD_ATTR                6 (stdin)
             67 GET_ITER         
        >>   68 FOR_ITER                16 (to 87)
             71 STORE_NAME               7 (line)
 11          74 LOAD_NAME                4 (count)
             77 LOAD_CONST               4 (1)
             80 INPLACE_ADD      
             81 STORE_NAME               4 (count)
             84 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           68
        >>   87 POP_BLOCK
```

And byte code for corresponding part of second script is:

```
 12          18 SETUP_LOOP              24 (to 45)
             21 LOAD_FAST                0 (input)
             24 GET_ITER
        >>   25 FOR_ITER                16 (to 44)
             28 STORE_FAST               3 (line)
 13          31 LOAD_FAST                1 (count)
             34 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             37 INPLACE_ADD
             38 STORE_FAST               1 (count)
             41 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           25
        >>   44 POP_BLOCK
```

I see that actual difference between this codes is LOAD_NAME vs LOAD_FAST and STORE_NAME vs STORE_FAST opcodes using.
Documentation http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST says that
LOAD_FAST makes lookup using only indexes, while LOAD_NAME lookups variable by string name.
And the first approach is two times faster.

Comment: Standard python 'dis' module can disassemble almost all :)