# Is there a faster way to load a file in C++ using the command line?

Tags: c++, file, input, command-line

I want to load one million random integers from a .txt into a vector using the command line:

```
program.exe < million-integers.txt
```

My code below works, but takes several seconds to run. Is there something I can do to make it faster? I've found some solutions on SO, but they all seem to relying on hard-coding the filepath. I want to be able to pass a filename through the command line.

```
vector<int> data;
int input;

while (cin >> input)
{
    data.push_back(input);
}
cout << "Data loaded." << endl;
```

(C++ noob using Visual Studio on Win 8.1)

**Edit**: In this case, I know that some improvement can be made since I have someone else's .exe that can do it in under a second.

**Edit**: All integers are on the same line.

Comment: How did you build the program? Did you do it in release mode, with all optimisations turned on?

Comment: You should consider [`reserve`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/)ing space for the values in your `std::vector`. Otherwise, it's going to be resizing and copying elements over and over again, like [Schlemiel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schlemiel_the_painter%27s_Algorithm#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: @Lilshieste: At most, `reserve()` will save 50% of the execution time, and I seriously doubt it will more than a couple percent.

Comment: @Lilshieste: Good point. I didn't think of that.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Where did you come up with that 50% figure?

Comment: I used "Build Solution" with all default settings.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: I did the math wrong, it would be 67%.  Count memory bandwidth.  To populate the vector, you need to do at least one read and one write for every element.  To resize the vector, the same thing applies.  The worst-case number of copies due to resize is less than 2 per element.  I had wrongly thought it was 1 per element.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Number of copies != Time taken to perform copies

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's an estimate.  I think something fishy is going on with the C++ implementation that's making it slow.

Comment: @JimV my answer has been down voted into oblivion but I have posted a gist of how I managed to make it 10 times faster. I hope this is the solution you were looking for.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: Yeah there's something odd going on here.

Comment: @JimV You want to accept any of the answers? Were you able to resolve your issue?

Comment: @Spundun At this point I don't understand enough to implement half of these, but I'll keep at it. For now I just accepted the more in depth of the highest voted answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run time: 4.08s.  What?  That's slow!

## Why is this happening?

I did profiling.  I'm using a very different system: OS X 10.8, with Clang, but my program is *also* slow, and I suspect it is for the same reason.  Here are two lines from the profiling results (apologies for formatting):

```
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
3389.0ms   79.3%    76.0             std::__1::num_get<char, std::__1::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::do_get(std::__1::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >, std::__1::ios_base&, unsigned int&, long&) const
824.0ms   19.2% 8.0          std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_istream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)
```

As you can see, these two functions account for almost 98.5% of the execution time.  Wow!  When I drill down, what are these library functions calling that takes so much time?

- `flockfile()`
- `funlockfile()`
- `pthread_mutex_unlock()`

So, on my system, the implementation for `std::cin` works with C's `<stdio.h>` functions so they can both be used in the same program, and these functions make sure to synchronize with other threads.  This is inefficient.

1. There is no code using `<stdio.h>`, so there is no need synchronize with it.
2. There is only one thread using stdin, so locking is excessive, **especially** if you lock once per character read.  That's super excessive.  Locks and system calls are pretty fast... but if you do something like 10 million locks and system calls?  No longer fast.

**Note:** Yes, I am running OS X, and the actual functions will be different on Windows.  Instead of `flockfile()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` you will see whatever the Windows version is.

### Solution #1

Stop using redirection.  If you use `ifstream`, then it is assumed that you will take care of locking yourself.  On my system, this give a runtime of 0.42 seconds—close to a factor of 10.

### Solution #2

Read everything into a string, and then parse the string.  This allows you to continue using redirection to read the file.

### Solution #3

Disable locking on `std::cin`.  Sorry folks, I don't know how to do that.  It might be possible.

### Performance limits

I suspect the `ifstream` version is nowhere near the performance limit of your computer.  If performance were critical, I suspect you can get the warm-cache runtime close to 2 or 3 ms, when your program is only limited by memory bandwidth.

Comment: In Xcode, press command-I, or select "Profile" from the Product menu.  This will launch Instruments.  I used the "time profiler".  Make sure to set any necessary command-line arguments in advance (Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Arguments Passed On Launch).

Comment: Awesome! But I wonder how you redirected a file for profiling this way.

Comment: @Spundun: I used `int fdes = open(path, O_RDONLY)` and then `dup2(fdes, 0)`, which is the same way Bash does it.  It's a bit of a hack to do it after the program starts.

Comment: pthread_mutex_lock done properly should not make any system calls unless there is contention.

Comment: @droon: Right, as I said, they are library functions, and there is no contention.

Comment: There is a sync_with_stdio option you can disable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yxhba01.aspx

Answer (score 5):

There are two things you might try.

1. use `std::vector<T>::reserve` to size your vector up front
2. use `std::iostream::read` to read the data in 4K (or bigger) blocks and parse the data yourself.

`iostream`s are supposed to be buffered and vectors are suppose to have a good resize strategy but sometimes these things do not work as well as expected.

Comment: The main(90%) performance penalty comes from using cin instead of ifstream. Because cin tries to be thread safe. See my answer and Dietrich's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular `ifstream` instead of `cin`. Pass the name of the file on command line (`vargs`) and open it, instead of using `cin`.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  vector<int> data;
  int input;
  ifstream in;
  in.open(argv[1]);
 
  while (in >> input)
  {
        data.push_back(input);
  }
  cout << "Data loaded." << endl;
}
```

@DietrichEpp shed more light on why my solution was 10 times faster. When you use cin, it tries to be thread safe and adds extra synchronization overhead making it run much slower.

---

I have verified that [my solution](https://gist.github.com/spundun/c91c07d7b8233e675d2e) works and it runs 10 times faster. I'm using MacBook Pro (2012 I think) with a flash drive

```
cpp $ruby gen_data.rb > data.txt 
cpp $c++ -O3 test1.cpp 
cpp $time ./a.out < data.txt 
Data loaded.

real    0m3.048s
user    0m3.023s
sys 0m0.011s
cpp $c++ -O3 test2.cpp 
cpp $time ./a.out data.txt 
data.txtData loaded.

real    0m0.351s
user    0m0.334s
sys 0m0.010s
```

Comment: This is not how file redirection works.  When you use shell redirection with bash, the standard input file descriptor is just a regular file—which is *exactly* the same thing you get if you open the file using a path.  You can even seek on it!  There is *zero* overhead.  I suggest reading about how `fork()` and `exec()` work with respect to file descriptors, although the question is on Windows 8.1, which makes everything different.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Ok, as hard as it was to receive criticism. At first I thought maybe you are right, after all what I had said was an educated guess, I don't have all the bash, fork, exec, pipe and filesystem implementation at the tip of my tongue. But fortunately I took the time to verify my answer, and I'm actually getting around 90% gain in time. Please verify this. I think mine is the right answer.

Comment: You have done some research, but the difference here is between `ifstream` and `std::cin`, and it has nothing to do with Bash.  Your explanation for *why* is still wrong.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I'm not claiming that bash is at fault, I'm just explaining how the data is ending up in the program in two scenarios. I did say that he is using stdin and pipe instead of straight file io. While I may not have explained in detail where the performance bottelneck occures, I don't think I led him in the wrong direction. I meant to tell him that there might be overhead associated with this system because it has more components.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the effect of file system caching? Run the same test but in the opposite order.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I have run the tests 3 times already but I'll do what you said for completeness

Comment: @Blastfurnace still the same result

Comment: @DietrichEpp I have updated my explanation to hopefully clarify what I'm trying to say. What does everyone think now?

Comment: Try putting `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` at the top of main in `test1.cpp`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace still same numbers.

Comment: @Spundun: The problem with your explanation is that you say there is a pipe.  This is wrong, there is no pipe.  When you redirect a file using `<`, you get a handle to the file directly, and no pipe is created.  There is *zero* communication between bash and the program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp if that is correct then you are right, I need to fix my answer. is there anywhere this is documented?

Comment: I can elaborate.  When bash uses `<`, it opens the file.  Then when it forks, that file descriptor is passed to the child process and with `dup2()` becomes file descriptor #0, and then bash uses `exec()` to start your program.  When you use `ifstream`, you get a different file descriptor (probably #3), and you open it after `exec()`, but it's still the exact same kind of file descriptor, with the exact same system calls used to read it, and it reads directly from the file with no help from bash.  You could read a Unix programming book, any good Unix programming book explains this.

Comment: @DietrichEpp Thanks, for the support. I understand your explanation. It does sound like a good way to implement the bash < feature. So that's why you think the performance improvement is coming solely from cin specific quirks?

Comment: @Spundun: Yes, according to my profiling, most of the performance penalty is because `std::cin` is built to work with multiple threads, but since there is only one thread working with `std::cin`, that effort is wasted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54818/discussion-between-spundun-and-dietrich-epp).

Answer (score 1):

Another option you may want to look into is `ios_base::sync_with_stdio`, which defaults to `true`. This options forces `std::cin` to read each block as a separate chunk in order to allow you to intertwine C operations with C++. This slows down reading a lot. A more detailed analysis can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python).

Comment: This doesn't seem to have any effect on runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and No.  Yes, there is a faster way to retrieve the data once the OS gives it to you.  No, your program is at the mercy of the OS and the OS will send data from the file to your program as the OS chooses (There may be other tasks that can interrupt your program from receiving data continuously).

**Read large amounts into memory**
Memory is always faster to search than a device, such as a thumb drive or hard drive.

One read request for a large amount of data is usually much faster than many read requests for a small amount of data.

Combining these facts states that you should allocate (*reserve*) a large amount of memory and read into the memory.  This may need to be repeated depending on the amount of memory you can reserve and the size of the file.

Example:

```
  const unsigned int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;
  char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
  cin.read(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

**Use std::istringstream**
You can create an std::istringstream that uses the buffer.  Thus you can "read" your integers from the text buffer as you would from `cin` or a text file.

**Overhead of file redirection**
When you redirect the output of a file to the input of your program, the OS must open the file, read some data from the file, then pass it to your program.  This overhead is the principle bottleneck of your program.  If your program would open the file directly, you could avoid the overhead and make your program run faster.

Search the web for "C++ cin rdbuf setbuf" for information on redirecting `cin` to use a buffer of your choosing.

Comment: Are you sure that redirection has overhead?  At least on Unix systems, redirection has zero overhead whatsoever.

Comment: @DietrichEpp: So what you are saying is in Unix systems, the program opens the file directly when using input redirection?  My understanding is that the OS needs to switch the `cin` driver to use a file reading driver rather than a keyboard reading driver. My understanding your comment is that this file reading driver is the same driver used when a program opens and reads a file.  There is still overhead because of the switching to the file reading driver and reverting back to the keyboard reading driver.

Comment: Any good book on Unix programming has the details, but here's the summary.  Forget about drivers, those are in the kernel and irrelevant here.  Open files are identified by number, and #0 is standard input.  You can put any file in slot #0, such as a handle to a terminal window, a regular file, or a network socket: to the program, they're all just file handles.  In the terminal, normally #0 is a pipe hooked up to the terminal program.  When you use `<` in bash, instead, #0 is just a regular file.

Comment: If you open a file from within a program, the only difference is that the file number will be different, and *only* because file #0 is already in use.  So if you call `fopen()` or `open()` or create an `ifstream`, you probably get file #3 or #4 instead.  But it is still exactly the same kind of file as if you use `<` in bash: just a regular file, not a pipe.