# Why is Python faster than C++ in this case?

Tags: python, c++, performance, io

A program in both Python and C++ is given below, which performs the following task: read white-space delimited words from stdin, print the unique words sorted by string length along with a count of each unique word to stdout. The format for a line of the output is: length, count, word.

For exmaple, with this input file (488kB of a thesaurus)
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NeUBQ22T

The output, with formatting, is this:

```
1 57 "
1 1 n
1 1 )
1 3 *
1 18 ,
1 7 -
1 1 R
1 13 .
1 2 1
1 1 S
1 5 2
1 1 3
1 2 4
1 2 &
1 91 %
1 1 5
1 1 6
1 1 7
1 1 8
1 2 9
1 16 ;
1 2 =
1 5 A
1 1 C
1 5 e
1 3 E
1 1 G
1 11 I
1 1 L
1 4 N
1 681 a
1 2 y
1 1 P
2 1 67
2 1 y;
2 1 P-
2 85 no
2 9 ne
2 779 of
2 1 n;
...
```

Here is the program in C++

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

bool compare_strlen (const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
  return (lhs.length() < rhs.length());
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::string str;
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  /* Extract words from the input file, splitting on whitespace */
  while (std::cin >> str) {
    words.push_back(str);
  }

  /* Extract unique words and count the number of occurances of each word */
  std::set<std::string> unique_words;
  std::map<std::string,int> word_count; 
  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = words.begin();
       it != words.end(); ++it) {
    unique_words.insert(*it);
    word_count[*it]++;
  }

  words.clear();
  std::copy(unique_words.begin(), unique_words.end(),
            std::back_inserter(words));

  // Sort by word length 
  std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), compare_strlen);

  // Print words with length and number of occurances
  for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = words.begin();
       it != words.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->length() << " " << word_count[*it]  << " " <<
              *it << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Here is the Program in Python:

```py
import fileinput
from collections import defaultdict

words = set()
count = {}
for line in fileinput.input():
  line_words = line.split()
  for word in line_words:
    if word not in words:
      words.add(word)
      count[word] = 1
    else:
      count[word] += 1 

words = list(words)
words.sort(key=len)

for word in words:
  print len(word), count[word], word
```

For the C++ program, the compiler used was g++ 4.9.0 with the -O3 flag.

The version of Python used was 2.7.3

Time taken for the C++ program:

```sh
time ./main > measure-and-count.txt < ~/Documents/thesaurus/thesaurus.txt

real    0m0.687s
user    0m0.559s
sys     0m0.123s
```

Time taken for the Python program:

```sh
time python main.py > measure-and-count.txt < ~/Documents/thesaurus/thesaurus.txt

real    0m0.369s
user    0m0.308s
sys     0m0.029s
```

The Python program is much faster than the C++ program, and is relatively even faster with larger input sizes. What's going on here? Is my use of the C++ STL incorrect?

**Edit:**
As suggested by a comment and an answer, I changed the C++ program to use `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map`.

The following lines were changed

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

...

std::unordered_set<std::string> unique_words;
std::unordered_map<std::string,int> word_count;
```

The compilation command:

```sh
g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -O3 -o main main.cpp
```

This improved performance only marginally:

```sh
time ./main > measure-and-count.txt < ~/Documents/thesaurus/thesaurus.txt

real    0m0.604s
user    0m0.479s
sys     0m0.122s
```

**Edit2:** A much faster program in C++

This is a combination of NetVipeC's solution, Dieter Lücking's solution, and the top answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python). The real performance killer was `cin` using an **unbuffered read** by default. Solved with `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);`. This solution also uses a single container, taking advantage of the ordered `map` in C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

struct comparer_strlen {
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
        if (lhs.length() == rhs.length())
            return lhs < rhs;
        return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);

    std::string str;

    typedef std::map<std::string, int, comparer_strlen> word_count_t;

    /* Extract words from the input file, splitting on whitespace */
    /* Extract unique words and count the number of occurances of each word */
    word_count_t word_count;
    while (std::cin >> str) {
        word_count[str]++;
    }

    // Print words with length and number of occurances
    for (word_count_t::iterator it = word_count.begin();
         it != word_count.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->first.length() << " " << it->second << " "
                  << it->first << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Runtime

```
time ./main3 > measure-and-count.txt < ~/Documents/thesaurus/thesaurus.txt

real    0m0.106s
user    0m0.091s
sys     0m0.012s
```

**Edit3:** A nice and concise version of the Python program was provided by Daniel, it runs in about the same time as the version above:

```
import fileinput
from collections import Counter

count = Counter(w for line in fileinput.input() for w in line.split())

for word in sorted(count, key=len):
  print len(word), count[word], word
```

Runtime:

```
time python main2.py > measure-and-count.txt.py < ~/Documents/thesaurus/thesaurus.txt

real    0m0.342s
user    0m0.312s
sys     0m0.027s
```

Comment: `std::map` vs `std::unordered_map` ?

Comment: I'm not confident enough to dupe-hammer this, but here's the possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python

Comment: btw. Python is used for its shortness and not speed: `count = Counter(l for line in fileinput.input() for l in line.split())
for word in sorted(count, key=len):
    print len(word), count[word], word`

Comment: Try to lower the optimization settings. Having `-O3` can in certain cases *lower* performance. Experiment with different optimization settings. Also try marking the comparison function `inline`.

Comment: -O2 is slightly slower on my machine ~(-10ms)

Comment: What happens if you replace std::endl with '\n' maybe the difference is just the repeated flush from std::endl?

Comment: Try `unordered` now that you have the big bottleneck killed.  It may save another huge chunk...

Comment: The third solution in my post, as opposed to the second, actually uses the ordered `map` to sort during insertion.

Comment: @OregonTrail yes, but the speedup from `unordered_` during building of the count *may* make up for making a `std::vector` and sorting it afterwards.  It might not, but it might.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test with this, it must be faster than the original C++.

Changes are:

- Eliminated the vector `words` to save the words (there will be saved already in word_count).
- Eliminated the set `unique_words` (in word_count are only the unique words).
- Eliminated the second copy to words, not needed.
- Eliminated the sort of the words (the order was updated in the map, now the words in the map are order by length and the words with same length are lexicographically order.

  ```
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  #include <iostream>
  #include <set>
  #include <map>

  struct comparer_strlen_functor {
      operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const {
          if (lhs.length() == rhs.length())
              return lhs < rhs;
          return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
      }
  };

  int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
      std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);

      std::string str;

      typedef std::map<std::string, int, comparer_strlen_functor> word_count_t;

      /* Extract words from the input file, splitting on whitespace */
      /* Extract unique words and count the number of occurances of each word */
      word_count_t word_count;
      while (std::cin >> str) {
          word_count[str]++;
      }

      // Print words with length and number of occurances
      for (word_count_t::iterator it = word_count.begin(); it != word_count.end();
           ++it) {
          std::cout << it->first.length() << " " << it->second << " " << it->first
                    << "\n";
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

New version of the reading loop, to read line by line and split. Need `#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>`

```
while (std::getline(std::cin, str)) {
    for (string_split_iterator It = boost::make_split_iterator(
             str, boost::first_finder(" ", boost::is_iequal()));
         It != string_split_iterator(); ++It) {
        if (It->end() - It->begin() != 0)
            word_count[boost::copy_range<std::string>(*It)]++;
    }
}
```

Testing in Core i5, 8GB RAM, GCC 4.9.0, 32bits, run in 238ms. Updated the code with `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` and `\n` as proposed.

Comment: Your version only marginally faster at `0.540s` on my machine.

Comment: `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -O3 -o main2 main2.cpp`

Comment: You are executing multiple time both programs?

Comment: Yes, the proper way to measure performance would be an average of many runs. In this case I see performance within +-5ms running the test 10 or so times before pasting a representative result.

Comment: I do like your use of the STL better than mine, as you take advantage of the ordered `map` which I was not aware of.

Comment: As noted below, `std::endl` is not "end of line", but rather "end of line and flush".  Use `"\n"` if you do not need a flush.

Comment: I like this answer because it takes **advantage** of the ordering property of the default `map` in STL. However, most of the speedup in the final answer was from using `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` and `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`.

Answer (score 2):

Making three changes, omitting the extra vector (which you not have in python), reserve memory for the word-vector and avoiding the endl (!) in the output:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <map>

bool compare_strlen (const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
  return (lhs.length() < rhs.length());
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    /* Extract words from the input file, splitting on whitespace */
    /* Also count the number of occurances of each word */
    std::map<std::string, int> word_count;
    {
        std::string str;
        while (std::cin >> str) {
            ++word_count[str];
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    words.reserve(word_count.size());
    for(std::map<std::string, int>::const_iterator w = word_count.begin();
        w != word_count.end();
        ++w)
    {
        words.push_back(w->first);
    }

    // Sort by word length
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), compare_strlen);

    // Print words with length and number of occurances
    for (std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = words.begin();
       it != words.end();
       ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->length() << " " << word_count[*it]  << " " <<
                  *it << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Gives:

Original:

```
real    0m0.230s
user    0m0.224s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Improved:

```
real    0m0.140s
user    0m0.132s
sys 0m0.004s
```

More Improved by adding `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` See OregonTrail's question):

```
real    0m0.107s
user    0m0.100s
sys 0m0.004s
```

And NetVipeC's solution with `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` and the replacement of std::endl by '\n':

```
real    0m0.077s
user    0m0.072s
sys 0m0.004s
```

Python:

```
real    0m0.146s
user    0m0.136s
sys 0m0.008s
```

Comment: Your version is still about 30% slower than Python on my machine, but is the fastest solution thus far.

Comment: Wow, removing `std::endl` from NetVipeC's solution makes his only about 8% slower than the Python program on my machine.

Comment: @OregonTrail - Same speed on mine (g++ -O3 main.cc -o Test)

Answer (score 1):

```
  std::vector<std::string> words;

  /* Extract words from the input file, splitting on whitespace */
  while (std::cin >> str) {
    words.push_back(str);
  }
```

This requires constantly repeating allocate/copy/free operations as the vector grows. Either pre-allocate the vector or use something like a list.

Comment: The Python program isn't doing any pre-allocation. Also, pre-allocating would require counting the words in the file.

Comment: @OregonTrail If you understand what I'm saying, your response is a non-sequiter. (And it doesn't require counting them. Just pre-allocating, say, a million entries, would be fine. Also, how do you know whether the Python program pre-allocates or not?)

Comment: Did you try it out though? I don't see a significant difference. I guess it is dominated by IO.

Comment: The Python program dynamically grows the `set()`, Python must `realloc()` this data structure (at least the hash table, unless it has an unusually large default size for `set()`). Also, to **never** have the vector copy itself in the `C++` program, it would have to count the words in the input file in advance, and then rewind the file.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I think you're close. I believe Python must be using some form of buffered read from the input file. cin will not buffer the file in memory, so each read takes IO. Instead, one should read in the whole file (or in batches) and perform the parsing in memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your C++ code.

First, you are using mutable strings.  Which means you are copying them around a bunch.  (Python strings are immutable).  Testing for this, I find the effect can actually make the C++ code slower, so lets drop this one.

Second, `unordered_` containers are probably a good idea.  Testing this, I get a 1/3 speedup by swapping them in/out (using `boost::hash` algorithm for hashing).

Third, your use of `std::endl` flushes `std::cout` on each line.  That seems silly.

Forth, `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` to reduce overhead of `std::cin`, or don't use them.

Fifth, directly construct the `set` and `map` from io, don't round-trip through a `std::vector` needlessly.

Here is a [test program](http://ideone.com/Nw90cc) (with hard coded data of about 1/4th the size) with immutable strings (`std::shared_ptr<const std::string>`) and `unordered_` containers with manual hash setups, and a few C++11 features to make the code a bit shorter.

Strip out the large `R"(` string literal, and replace the `stringstream` with `std::cin`.

For more performance, don't use the heavy-weight streaming objects.  They do a lot of really, really paranoid work.

Comment: To your last point, using `std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);` gave me a 4x speedup. The latest version is at the bottom of the original post.

Comment: @OregonTrail Updated.  About 5x faster than it was (0.05 down to 0.01).  Includes code to easily swap between smart-pointer based strings and by-value strings, and unordered vs ordered containers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another C++ version that I believe more closely matches the python line-by-line.  It attempts to retain the same types of containers and operations found in the python version, with obvious C++ specific tweaks.  Note that I lifted the `sync_with_stdio` optimization from the other answers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <list>

#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>


bool compare_strlen(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs)
{
    return lhs.length() < rhs.length();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::unordered_set<std::string> words;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::size_t> count;

    // Make std::cin use its own buffer to improve I/O performance.
    std::cin.sync_with_stdio(false);

    // Extract words from the input file line-by-line, splitting on
    // whitespace
    char line[128] = {};  // Yes, std::vector or std::array would work, too.
    while (std::cin.getline(line, sizeof(line) / sizeof(line[0]))) {
        // Tokenize
        std::istringstream line_stream(line);
        std::istream_iterator<std::string> const end;
        for(std::istream_iterator<std::string> i(line_stream);
            i != end;
            ++i) {
            words.insert(*i);
            count[*i]++;
        }
    }

    std::list<std::string> words_list(words.begin(), words.end());
    words_list.sort(compare_strlen);

    // Print words with length and number of occurences
    for (auto const & word : words_list)
        std::cout << word.length()
                  << ' ' << count[word]
                  << ' ' << word
                  << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The results are comparable to your original python code and @NetVipeC's C++.

**C++**

```
real    0m0.979s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.016s
```

**Python**

```
real    0m0.993s
user    0m0.112s
sys     0m0.060s
```

I was a bit surprised this version of the C++ performed comparably to the other streamlined C++ answers to your question, since I thought for sure things like the `stringstream` based tokenizing would be a bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

Both `std::set` and `std::map` are optimized for lookups, not insertion. They must be sorted/tree-balanced every time you change the contents. You might try using `std::unordered_set` and `std::unordered_map` which are hash-based and would be faster for your use case.

Comment: Added results for using the `unordered` containers, only marginal performance improvement.