# estimating number of lines in a file - mismatch between file size and size of all lines

Tags: python, file, io, filesize, disk

I have a few hundred files, each a between 10s of MB and a few GB in size, and I'd like to estimate the number of lines (i.e. an exact count is not needed).  Each line is very regular, for example something like 4 long ints and 5 double floats.

I tried to find the average size of the first `AVE_OVER` lines in a file, then use that to estimate the total number of lines:

```
nums = sum(1 for line in open(files[0]))
print "Number of lines = ", nums

AVE_OVER = 10
lineSize = 0.0
count = 0
for line in open(files[0]):
    lineSize += sys.getsizeof(line)
    count += 1
    if( count >= AVE_OVER ): break

lineSize /= count
fileSize = os.path.getsize(files[0])
numLines = fileSize/lineSize
print "Estimated number of lines = ", numLines
```

The estimate was way off:

```
> Number of lines =  505235
> Estimated number of lines =  324604.165863
```

So I tried counting the total size of all lines in the file, compared to the `sys` measured size:

```
fileSize = os.path.getsize(files[0])
totalLineSize = 0.0
for line in open(files[0]):
totalLineSize += sys.getsizeof(line)

print "File size = %.3e" % (fileSize)
print "Total Line Size = %.3e" % (totalLineSize)
```

But again these are discrepant!

```
> File size = 3.366e+07
> Total Line Size = 5.236e+07
```

**Why is the sum of sizes of each lines so much larger than the actual total file size?  How can I correct for this?**

---

### Edit:  **Algorithm I ended up with** (ver 2.0); Thanks to @J.F.Sebastian

```
def estimateLines(files):
    """ Estimate the number of lines in the given file(s) """

    if( not np.iterable(files) ): files = [files]
    LEARN_SIZE = 8192

    # Get total size of all files                                                                                                                                                                   
    numLines = sum( os.path.getsize(fil) for fil in files )

    with open(files[0], 'rb') as file:
         buf = file.read(LEARN_SIZE)
         numLines /= (len(buf) // buf.count(b'\n'))

    return numLines
```

Comment: @OlehPrypin "<built-in function getsizeof> \
Docstring: getsizeof(object, default) -> int \
Return the size of object in bytes."  Yeah, God, I'm so dumb for not intuiting that this wouldn't give me the size of the object I was looking at... How could I be so stupid?!  Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: `line.count(b'\n')` is `1` (or `0` if there is no newline at the end of the file). Don't use together `for line in file` and `line.count(b'\n')`: it is useless. Use one or the other. The latter is faster. `def estimateLines(filename): return os.path.getsize(filename) // line_size_hint(filename)`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thanks for the feedback.  I was trying to implement an average over the first few lines instead --- but now I understand yours already does that (well, up to 8192 bytes).

Comment: If you want to avoid estimating the line size for a each file and use the line size hint computed based on the first file then to estimate number of lines in several files, you could use `numLines = sum(map(os.path.getsize, files)) // line_size_hint(files[0])`.

Comment: *1)* Remove `if not np.iterable(files): files = [files]`. It does nothing because a `str`/`unicode` instances are iterable (types that are acceptable by `open()` in Python 2). Do you expect a (buffer) type that is not iterable but that is accepted by `open()`? *2)* Use `//=` for compatibility with Python 3. *3)* Why don't you want to refactor the code fragment into `line_size_hint()` function (the function call overhead should be negligible compared to all the I/O)? *4)* Don't put *answer* (the solution) in to the question, post it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To estimate number of lines in a file:

```
def line_size_hint(filename, learn_size=1<<13):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
        buf = file.read(learn_size)
        return len(buf) // buf.count(b'\n')

number_of_lines_approx = os.path.getsize(filename) // line_size_hint(filename)
```

To find the exact number of lines, you could [use `wc-l.py` script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python#comment11966378_9371238):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from functools import partial

print(sum(chunk.count('\n') for chunk in iter(partial(sys.stdin.read, 1 << 15), '')))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.getsizeof` is the sole cause of problems here. It gives arbitrary implementation-dependent sizes of objects and shouldn't be used at all, except for very rare cases.

Just open the file as binary and get actual lengths of the lines using `len`.