# CompletedProcess from subprocess.run() doesn't return a string

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5

According to the [Python 3.5 docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess), subprocess.run() returns an a CompletedProcess object with a stdout member that contains "A bytes sequence, or a string if run() was called with universal_newlines=True." I'm only seeing a byte sequence and not a string, which I was assuming (hoping) would be equivalent to a text line. For example,

```
import pprint
import subprocess

my_data = ""
line_count = 0

proc = subprocess.run(
         args = [ 'cat', 'input.txt' ],
         universal_newlines = True,
         stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

for text_line in proc.stdout:
    my_data += text_line
    line_count += 1

word_file = open('output.txt', 'w')
pprint.pprint(my_data, word_file)
pprint.pprint(line_count, word_file)
```

Note: this uses a new feature in Python 3.5 that won't run in previous versions.

Do I need to create my own line buffering logic, or is there a way to get Python to do that for me?

Comment: This doesn't even run for me (in 3.4) -- is that expected?

Comment: I'm using 3.5. I'll make it more clear.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting a byte sequence? You may `print type(proc.stdout)` or something to check. You're iterating over `proc.stdout` as though it's a file. Iterating over an open text file gives you each line. Iterating over a string or byte sequence give you each character/byte. If you want to handle each line of a string individually, you could iterate over `proc.stdout.split('\n')` instead. (Though this won't include newlines in each line like iterating over a file would.)

Comment: Thanks. Chaining split() to proc.stdout was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`proc.stdout` is already a string in your case, run `print(type(proc.stdout))`, to make sure. It contains all subprocess' output -- `subprocess.run()` does not return until the child process is dead.

`for text_line in proc.stdout:` is incorrect: `for char in text_string` enumerates characters (Unicode codepoints) in Python, not lines. To get lines, call:

```
lines = result.stdout.splitlines()
```

The result may be different from `.split('\n')` if there are Unicode newlines in the string.

If you want to read the output line by line (to avoid running out of memory for long-running processes):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True) as process:
    for line in process.stdout:
        do_something_with(line)
```

Note: `process.stdout` is a file-like object in this case. `Popen()` does not wait for the process to finish -- `Popen()` returns immidiately as soon as the child process is started. `process` is a `subprocess.Popen` instance, not `CompletedProcess` here.

If all you need is to count the number of lines (terminated by `b'\n'`) in the output, like `wc -l`:

```
from functools import partial

with Popen(command, stdout=PIPE) as process:
    read_chunk = partial(process.stdout.read, 1 << 13)
    line_count = sum(chunk.count(b'\n') for chunk in iter(read_chunk, b''))
```

See [Why is reading lines from stdin much slower in C++ than Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9371238/4279)

Comment: There is a typing error.
"from subprocess" instead of "from subrocess".
But this works for me, thank you.

Answer (score 7):

if you need to have STDOUT lines in an array to better manipulate them you simply miss to split output by the "Universal newline" separators

```
nmap_out = subprocess.run(args = ['nmap', '-T4', '-A', '192.168.1.128'],
                              universal_newlines = True,
                              stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

nmap_lines = nmap_out.stdout.splitlines()
print(nmap_lines)
```

output is:

```
['Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-02-28 12:24 CET', 'Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn', 'Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.37 seconds']
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeing a string, compare:

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.run(
    args = [ 'cat', 'input.txt' ],
    universal_newlines = False,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

print (type(proc.stdout))
```

class 'bytes'

run calls popen.communicate

> communicate() returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data). The data
>   will be bytes or, if universal_newlines was True, strings.

Have a look [here](https://pymotw.com/2/subprocess/index.html#module-subprocess) for more explanation and other shell interactions.