# Execution time difference in C++ codes

Tags: c++, boost, time

This question is in reference to this question of mine
[Time Difference between the execution of the C++ program with and without print statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065877/time-difference-with-cout-and-without-cout-in-c-in-program-execution?noredirect=1#comment108040625_61065877).

Look at these codes:

### 1) Without `print` statement:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using big_int = boost:: multiprecision:: cpp_int;
using namespace std;
clock_t start = clock();

int main() {
    for(big_int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
    }
    double elapsedTime = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << endl << "Time is " << elapsedTime << " Seconds";
    return 0;
}
```

Execution Time:

#### Time is 0.370125 Seconds

### 2) With `print` statement

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
using big_int = boost:: multiprecision:: cpp_int;
using namespace std;
clock_t start = clock();


int main() {
    for(big_int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) {
         cout << i << endl;
    }
    double elapsedTime = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << endl << "Time is " << elapsedTime << " Seconds";
    return 0;
}
```

Execution Time:

#### Time is 26.8947 Seconds

I want to know that like these two codes why there is not a significant difference in the execution time of the codes mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61065877/time-difference-with-cout-and-without-cout-in-c-in-program-execution?noredirect=1#comment108040625_61065877) question.

Comment: a smart compiler can optimize out empty loops. and writing to `cout` takes a hit calling the system calls.

Comment: So, it is nothing to do with overhead related to the output buffer?

Comment: Are you asking this new question to get an answer for your other question? Why don't you edit that question to make it clearer.

Comment: Here you're comparing an empty loop and a loop that prints something. No work versus some work. Your other question compares a loop that does a lot of work and a loop that does the same work but adds a single print statement. Your time in other code is dominated by the computation, not the single additional print.

Comment: Because the previous question contains already large amount of code, So I thought it's better to ask a new to clarify

Comment: No, you need a single question, not another question seeking clarification for the previous question.

Comment: OK, @Blastfurnace I will take care of this in the future.