# DFS giving TLE in kefa and park (codeforces 560C)

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, depth-first-search

> Kefa decided to celebrate his first big salary by going to the
>   restaurant.
>
> He lives by an unusual park. The park is a rooted tree consisting of n
>   vertices with the root at vertex 1. Vertex 1 also contains Kefa's
>   house. Unfortunaely for our hero, the park also contains cats. Kefa
>   has already found out what are the vertices with cats in them.
>
> The leaf vertices of the park contain restaurants. Kefa wants to
>   choose a restaurant where he will go, but unfortunately he is very
>   afraid of cats, so there is no way he will go to the restaurant if the
>   path from the restaurant to his house contains more than m consecutive
>   vertices with cats.
>
> Your task is to help Kefa count the number of restaurants where he can
>   go.
>
> Input The first line contains two integers, n and m (2 ≤ n ≤ 105,
>   1 ≤ m ≤ n) — the number of vertices of the tree and the maximum number
>   of consecutive vertices with cats that is still ok for Kefa.
>
> The second line contains n integers a1, a2, ..., an, where each ai
>   either equals to 0 (then vertex i has no cat), or equals to 1 (then
>   vertex i has a cat).
>
> Next n - 1 lines contains the edges of the tree in the format "xi yi"
>   (without the quotes) (1 ≤ xi, yi ≤ n, xi ≠ yi), where xi and yi are
>   the vertices of the tree, connected by an edge.
>
> It is guaranteed that the given set of edges specifies a tree.
>
> Output A single integer — the number of distinct leaves of a tree the
>   path to which from Kefa's home contains at most m consecutive vertices
>   with cats.
>
> Examples input
>
> 4 1
>
> 1 1 0 0
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 1 4
>
> output
>
> 2
>
> input
>
> 7 1
>
> 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 2 4
>
> 2 5
>
> 3 6
>
> 3 7
>
> output
>
> 2

This dfs algo is pretty much similar to many accepted submissions on this question, still getting tle... It's running well in custom cases... I'm unable to find where does it giving TLE

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll unsigned long long int 
#define ld long double
#define pb push_back
#define fillarray for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
using namespace std;

int give(auto edge,auto node,auto visited,int index,int m,int x)
{
    if(edge[index].size()==1&&index!=0)
    {
        if(x+node[index]<=m) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
    if(visited[index]) return 0;
    visited[index]=1;

    if(node[index]) x++;
    else x=0;

    if(x>m) return 0;

    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<edge[index].size();i++)
    {
        sum+=give(edge,node,visited,edge[index][i],m,x);
    }
    return sum;
}
int main() 
{
    int n,m; 
    cin>>n>>m;
    vector<vector<int>> edge(n);
    vector<bool> node(n);
    vector<bool> visited(n,0);

    fillarray{
        bool x; cin>>x;
        node[i]=x;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        int x,y;
        cin>>x>>y;
        edge[x-1].pb(y-1);
        edge[y-1].pb(x-1);
    }
    cout<<give(edge,node,visited,0,m,0);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371238/why-is-reading-lines-from-stdin-much-slower-in-c-than-python may be the problem.

Comment: @user202729 thnks, but it's still giving TLE.. can you look at my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass by reference:

```
int give(const auto& edge,const auto& node,auto& visited,int index,int m,int x)
```

With only this change i got the test passed.