# Question about using freopen() and cin, cout to read large input from file

Tags: c++

I want to ask a question about c++ i/o. If I use `cin`, `cout` with `freopen()`, is it necessary to put `sync_with_stdio(false)` or is there any way to speed it up? I noticed that using `cout` without `sync_with_stdio(false)` is a bit faster and it's no slower or faster than `scanf()`.

Reading with `sync_with_stdio(false)` and `cin` takes around 3.7 seconds
Reading without `sync_with_stdio(false)` takes around 6 seconds
With `scanf()` takes 1.7 seconds

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    freopen("i.inp", "r", stdin);
    freopen("o.out", "w", stdout);
    vector<int> a(10000000, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        //scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Writing with `sync_with_stdio(false)` and `cout` takes 2.7 seconds
and without `sync_with_stdio(false)` takes 2.5 seconds while `printf` being the fastest

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    freopen("i.inp", "r", stdin);
    freopen("o.out", "w", stdout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        cout << 1 << " ";
        //printf("%d", 1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While reading, `sync_with_stdio(false)` actually helps but writing with it takes longer which makes me a little confused and wondering if I should use it or not or just stick with `scanf` and `printf`.

I used codeblock for execution time measurement.

Comment: `sync_with_stdio(false)` is not necessary, but might give better performance. If it don't, then don't use it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371717/6486738) is an interesting discussion about it.

Comment: Please show a [mre], what is the input you are reading? What code are you using to read it? What performance are you getting? What performance do you require? Which platform are you running on?

Comment: Add some more info. With reading its a huge boost but with writing, its like it does the opposite

Comment: is there a reason you're using `freopen` rather than just using `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream`? Then `sync_with_stdio` wouldn't be an issue

Comment: I dont know if `fstream` gives any better performance. Might try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this case for sure but maybe you want to also try putting these two lines:

1. cin.tie(0); - > makes cin faster
2. cout.tie(0); - > makes cout faster
   and check the performance afterwards.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33561373)